# Initializing a class. Can you see any problems with this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

```
-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.name = [[NSString alloc] init];
        self.type = [[NSString alloc] init];
        self.phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc]init];
        self.webAddress = [[NSString alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *pricesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *poolsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.prices = pricesArray;
        self.pools = poolsArray;

        [pricesArray release];
        [poolsArray release];

        //Create the address dictionaries
        NSMutableDictionary *addressItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", KAddressStreet1Key, @"", KAddressStreet2Key, @"", KAddressBoroughKey, @"", KAddressCityKey, @"", KAddressCountyKey, @"", KAddressPostCodeKey, @"" ,KAddressCountryKey, nil];

        //Add dictionary to the array to contain address values
        self.address = addressItems;
        [addressItems release];

    }

    return self;
}
```

I'm currently doing a massive round of debugging thanks to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.. grr.

Does the code above seem fine and logical for a class init method? Basically I'm getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors when I release both the pools (mutable array and the dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're leaking objects with each allocation for the string properties. Other than that, I don't notice anything wrong. How are the AddressXKeys defined?

Comment: Ah ok thanks Barry. So the alloc is +1 and the copy property is also +1 to my retain count?

Address Keys are like this:
#define KAddressStreet1Key @"1address"

Comment: Yes, the copy property makes a copy of the string and keeps a reference to the copy, so the original is lost but has a retain count of +1. copy properties should be treated like retain properties for memory management purposes.

Comment: Freebie hint: the Cocoa pattern for string constants like this is to define a global string reference. This way you can compare pointers rather than using -[NSString isEqual:]. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c/539191#539191

Answer (score 1):

How are your properties declared?  If they are not declared with `retain` then most of your objects will be deallocated at the end of this method.

Comment: Ah yes apologies. collections are 'retain' and strings are 'copy'