# Using a constant NSString as the key for NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, default-value

I'm using NSUSerDefaults to store user preferences. I remember reading somewhere that setting the keys as constants is a good idea - and I agree. The following code is what I currently have:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:polygon.numberOfSides] 
           forKey:@"polygonNumberOfSides"];
```

I tried changing this to:

```
@implementation Controller

NSString const *kPolygonNumberOfSides = @"polygonNumberOfSides";

-(void)savePolygonInfo {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
            setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:polygon.numberOfSides] 
               forKey:kPolygonNumberOfSides];
}
```

While this does work, it produces "`warning: passing argument 1 of 'objectForKey:' discards qualifiers from pointer target type`". I'm keen to keep my code free from compiler warnings. How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You should use:

```
NSString * const kPolygonNumberOfSides = @"..."; // const pointer
```

instead of:

```
NSString const * kPolygonNumberOfSides = @"..."; // pointer to const
```

The first is a constant pointer to an NSString object, while the second is a pointer to a constant NSString object.

It is a subtle difference. The compiler warning happens because `setObject:forKey:` is declared as follows:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
```

It is expecting the `defaultName` argument to be of type `NSString *`. When you instead pass in a pointer to a constant, you've given it something different.

***Update:*** I want to point out that these constants should be defined as `static` if they are only going to be used from within a single file. I say this because I have run across this problem myself: if you do not declare them as static, then they will exist in the global namespace, and you will not be able to use a variable with the same the same name in another file. see [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) for more information. To explain by example, this is what I currently use for keys that I only need to use in one `.m` file:

```
static NSString * const kSomeLabel = @"...";
```

Comment: `NSString * const foo` works because `NSString` is immutable and the pointer is immutable so it can never change correct? Also, I recall from C++ that `const` is implicitly `static` (a compiler optimization) so no need to call it out. Is that true here as well?

Answer (score 33):

Don't use `const` with Objective-C objects, they weren't really designed to use it.  `NSString` objects (among many others) are already immutable by default by virtue of their design, so making them `const` is useless.

As [e.James suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753755/using-a-constant-nsstring-as-the-key-for-nsuserdefaults/753821#753821), you can use an `NSString * const`, which is a constant pointer to an `NSString`.  This is subtly different from a `const NSString *` (equivalent to `NSString const *`), which is a pointer to a constant `NSString`.  Using a `NSString * const` prevents you from reassigning `kPoly` to point to a new `NSString` object.

Comment: Good point about the use of const. That's why a lot of Objective-C classes have "Mutable" variants.

Comment: I thought that `const` also means you can't reassign it. I guess I had that wrong.

Comment: Given your 2nd paragraph, I think you should amend your first paragraph. Not being able to reassign an identifier is a valid use, and doesn't really have anything to do with mutability of the object itself. If you declare an NSString as ```NSString* const foo = @"bar"``` and then later try to reassign it, you'll get the error ```Cannot assign to variable 'foo'...``` which is exactly what I'd hope for when declaring something const.

Answer (score 18):

**For access from other classes:**

.h

```
extern NSString * const PolygonNumberOfSidesPrefsKey;
```

.m

```
NSString * const PolygonNumberOfSidesPrefsKey = @"PolygonNumberOfSides"
```

**For access only inside current class:**

.m

```
static NSString * const kPolygonNumberOfSidesPrefsKey = @"PolygonNumberOfSides"
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest even making the constant more descriptive. A constant for the number of sides of a polygon could come from anywhere. As a suggestion, how about:

```
kDefaultsPolygonNumberOfSides;
```

instead.