# error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: iphone, class

I've created a new class and i want to declare a NSDictionary containing a table of values so that it's available in the rest of my application.

I did it this way as a property of the class (modified):

```
NSDictionary *ell = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [[JFEllipsoid alloc] initWithRadius:6377563.396 withInvF:299.3249646], @"key1",                         
    [[JFEllipsoid alloc] initWithRadius:6377340.189 withInvF:299.3249646], @"key2",
nil};
```

When i compile i get this error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

How/Where can i declare this array of data so that it's available when i instance that class?

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

- [Objective-C error: initializer element is not constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/)

To make a long story short, you can try declaring your string data as `extern const`
 before using them, or you can change the scope of where you're declaring your NSDictionary.

Comment: Sorry for simplyfing so much. The point is the objects in the Dictionary are not strings. They'd be something like this:

NSDictionary *ell = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [[JFEllipsoid alloc] initWithRadius:6377563.396 withInvF:299.3249646], @"key1",       
 [[JFEllipsoid alloc] initWithRadius:6377340.189 withInvF:299.3249646], @"key2",
nil};