# How to declare NSString constants for passing to NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone

I've got the following in my .h file:

```
#ifndef _BALANCE_NOTIFICATION
#define _BALANCE NOTIFICATION
const NSString *BalanceUpdateNotification
#endif
```

and the following in my .m file:

```
const NSString *BalanceUpdateNotification = @"BalanceUpdateNotification";
```

I'm using this with the following codes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(updateBalance:)
    name:BalanceUpdateNotification
    object:nil];
```

and

```
[[NSNotificatoinCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:BalanceUpdateNotification
    object:self userInfo:nil];
```

Which works, but it gives me a warning:

```
Passing argument 1 of 'postNotificationName:object:userInfo' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

So, I can cast it to (NSString *), but I'm wondering what the proper way to do this is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`NSStrings` are immutable, so declaring a `const NSString *` would be redundant; just use `NSString *`.

If what you're trying to do is declare that the pointer itself can't change, that would be:

```
   NSString * const BalanceUpdateNotification = @"BalanceUpdateNotification";
```

See also
[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Comment: I made the same mistake as the questioner.  And you're right, you should put the const *after* the pointer.

Here's an example from Apple:


UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyboardDidShowNotification;

Comment: That is a great explanation of the ordering of the const keyword that I had never thought of before, thanks!

Answer (score 33):

Typically you declare the variable as `extern` in the header. The most idiomatic way seems to be like this:

#### Header

```
#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__

extern NSString * const BalanceUpdateNotification;

#endif
```

#### Source

```
#include "header.h"

NSString * const BalanceUpdateNotification = @"BalanceUpdateNotification";
```

`extern` tells the compiler that something of type `NSString * const` by the name of `BalanceUpdateNotification` exists somewhere. It could be in the source file that includes the header, but maybe not. It is not the compiler's job to ensure that it *does* exist, only that you are using it appropriately according to how you *typed* it. It is the linkers job to make sure that `BalanceUpdateNotification` actually has been defined somewhere, and only once.

Putting the `const` after the `*` means you can't reassign `BalanceUpdateNotification` to point to a different `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason not to use a constant literal with a preprocessor directive. `#import` does the job of inclusion guards, so you can simply say

```
#define AutomaticallyResumeDownloads @"AutomaticallyResumeDownloads"
```

and then #import the header containing that definition wherever it's needed.

Comment: I think it's perhaps that it is better to follow convention; your way has some upsides (i.e., it is simple and easily understandable), however all throughout Cocoa and AppKit headers you will regularly find "`extern NSString * const`" instead of preprocessor macros. By masking the actual value of the constant, developers are pushed towards reliance on the constant itself rather than the underlying value.

Comment: I like it, though yeah, I probably should have just looked at the headers to see what Apple does.

Comment: couldn't each @"AutomaticallyResumeDownloads" get a different pointer address, and be a different object?  I too prefer to go with Apple's standard on this which is NSString*

Comment: No. String literals are allocated statically, therefore each "instance" is guaranteed to have the same address. You can prefer the other way as a matter of style, but your contention is not an argument for or against it.

Comment: "therefore each "instance" is guaranteed to have the same address" This is actually an implementation detail and it's subject to cange

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one does not make these variables constant.  One would, on the other hand, declare them as externs in the header file.  This is (a little bit) because when you say `const NSString *string`, you are telling the compiler that the memory pointed to by string will not change -- this is both not useful and not necessarily true, being that we have no control over how apple's classes manage state variables. (Although NSStrings declared at runtime are placed in the text segment, functionality could change across versions or something.)  If you truly wanted to use const, which I still advise against, it should be `NSString * const string`, which will prevent the pointer from being altered to point to a different memory location (which it would not do otherwise);

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution to declare NSString name for observers.

```
static NSString *const MyCustomNotificationName = @"MyCustomNotificationName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a recommendation in [their own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1003095), where among other things, the macro `APPKIT_EXTERN` is used instead of `extern`. Combined with the contents of a default header file when created in Xcode, this is a complete implementation:

`Constants.h`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#ifndef Constants_h
#define Constants_h

APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *MyConstantName;

#endif
```

`Constants.m`:

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString *MyConstantName = @"MyConstantValue";
```

I think the above is more or less the standard way to achieve string constants, according to Apple.