# where to store constants in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Where do you store app configurations constants (not user preferences)?

- store in Info.plist?
- store in SomeOther.plist?
- store as static (extern?) constant in a .h?
- store as #define somewhere? (where?)

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they don't have to be preserved after the application is being closed AppDelegate is fine.
if they have to, then use NSUserDefaults class ;)

Comment: This isn't what the AppDelegate is for.

Answer (score 4):

I do it in a very oldskool C way. I have just a file like Constants.h where I go

```
#define SOMETHING value
```

And then I just #include "Constants.h" in my code and use SOMETHING.

Answer (score 0):

I store instance constants as a static in implementation class. Never had a global constant but I guess I would place it in the App delegate.

Answer (score -2):

Save them in NSUserDefaults. Here is a good example:

http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: NSUserDefaults is good for variable preferences, but overkill for constants.