# Constant in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, constants

I would like to add some constant keys for my application, these constants can be accessed anywhere in program. So I declare the constants in interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSString * MIN_INTERVAL_KEY = @"MIN_INTERVAL_KEY";
NSString * MAX_TOBACCO_KEY = @"MAX_TOBACCO_KEY";
NSString * ICON_BADGE = @"ICON_BADGE";

@interface SmokingViewController : UIViewController {
}
```

And I would like to access them from the MinIntervalViewController class:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (user) {
        self.selectedValue = [user objectForKey:MIN_INTERVAL_KEY];
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

But the application shows an error in the MinIntervalViewController class:

error: 'MIN_INTERVAL_KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)

Do I miss something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constants in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Constants.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Constants : NSObject {   

}

extern int const kExampleConstInt;
extern NSString * const kExampleConstString;

@end
```

Constants.m

```
#import "Constants.h"


@implementation Constants

int const kExampleConstInt = 1;
NSString * const kExampleConstString = @"String Value";

@end
```

To use:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

Then, simply call the specific variable you wish to use.

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithString:kExampleConstString];
```

Comment: Every line starting with an @ or } in your code can be removed, IMHO :-) There really is no need to define a class here.

Comment: This could be true, but leaving the class syntax in keeps the file consistent with every other header/implementation pair in an application. To each their own.

Answer (score 2):

In the .h file:

```
extern NSString * const MIN_INTERVAL_KEY;
```

In one (!) .m file:

```
NSString * const MIN_INTERVAL_KEY = @"MIN_INTERVAL_KEY";
```

And what you seemed to have missed is to actually `import` the header file declaring MIN_INTERVAL_KEY ;-) So if you declared it in `SmokingViewController.h` but like to use it in `MinIntervalViewController.m`, then you need to `import "SmokingViewController.h"` in your `MinIntervalViewController.m`. Since Objective-C is really more or less an extension to C all C visibility rules apply.

Also, what helps to debug things like that is to right-click on the .m file in Xcode and select "Preprocess". Then you see the file preprocess, i.e. after CPP has done its work. This is what the C compiler REALLY is digesting.