# Add DATE to Xcode xcconfig file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode config file, `Config.xcconfig` that contains this row only:

```
BUILD_DATE=`date "+%B %Y"`
```

I added this configuration to project in correct way, i hope.

[image]

I want to use the content of BUILD_DATE variable in the `Application-info.plist` file. How?

I tried get value using `${BUILD_DATE}` but result is the string ``date "+%B %Y"` not the value!

[image]

From terminal, result is correct:

```
alp$ BUILD_DATE=`date "+%B %Y"`
alp$ echo $BUILD_DATE
March 2013
alp$
```

but in Xcode no!

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: how you add Config.xcconfig file in configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the build date using the backtick command as the `.xcconfig` file is not interpreted as a shell script.

Your best bet is to use a similar approach the *Bump Build Number* script in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number) (that I asked a while back), which provides a solution for using an external build script to update the `.plist` file.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo usage: $0 plist-file
    exit 1
fi

plist="$1"
build_date=$(date "+%B %Y")

/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set BUILD_DATE \"$build_date\"" "$plist"
```

and invoke it from the Xcode Build Script using something like:

```
"${PROJECT_DIR}/tools/set_build_date.sh" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```