# How do I express NSDictionary as a literal in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, literals

Just like:

```
"APP_INFO" : {
            "v":"2.0",
            "appid":"1",
            "lang":"zh-Hans",
             }
```

I cannot use init methods because it's not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 12):

Starting in Clang 3.2, there's [literal container syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) available:

```
NSDictionary * d = @{
    @"APP_INFO" :  
    @{
        @"v" : @"2.0",
        @"appid" : @"1",
        @"lang" : @"zh-Hans",
}};
```

This creates an ordinary immutable `NSDictionary` instance, just as if you had used `alloc`/`initWithObjects:forKeys:` or any other method; it's simply nice syntactic sugar.

Rumor has it that Apple will be adding this to their compiler soon, too.

Comment: Not a rumor, it states clearly on the page you linked to:  "Users of Apple compiler releases can use these features starting with the Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0" ^^

Comment: Being syntactic sugar for a runtime initialization, you still can't make it const or put it in a header file, though. Only NSString literals can do that.

Comment: @richster, I got it. Only NSString can be made const in the header file, thx

Comment: @rickster: Why wouldn't it be able to be `const`? It's just a pointer:
 `NSDictionary * const d = [NSDictionary dictionary];`

Comment: @Josh Caswell, I do the same thing as [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855556/creating-a-constant-dictionary-object, but it gives me an error when init.

Comment: it tells me "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Comment: @Yifeng Li: Right, you can't send messages outside of a function or method.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the pointer itself can of course be made `const`.  The problem here is that this syntax just gets replaced with `[NSDictionary dictionaryWith...]` under the covers, which can't be done at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, that's in my answer: "This creates an ordinary immutable NSDictionary instance, just as if you had used `alloc`/`initWithObjects:forKeys:` or any other method; it's simply nice syntactic sugar.", @BenCollins.

Comment: @JoshCaswell right on.  I think the question needs to be edited a little, because as written, he's asking "how do I make a compile-time constant `NSDictionary`?", the answer to which is "You can't.".  He's actually asking "how do I express an `NSDictionary` as a literal?"

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2.0", @"v", @"1", @"appid", @"1", @"zh-Hans", @"lang", nil];
```

This creates an immutable dictionary whose contents are fixed at compile time.

You can use the same init method to populate a new dictionary at runtime:

```
id object1 = ...;
...
NSString *key1 = ...;
...

NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, key1, object2, key2, object3, key3, nil];
```