# How to declare my very own CGRectZero like constant?

Tags: objective-c, static, struct, constants, extern

This is a newbie C/Objective-C question :-)

Let say I want a CGRectOne and a CGRectTwo constants.

How can I declare that?

Thanks,
Jérémy

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The other answers are fine -*in some cases*-.

A) declaring it `static` will emit a copy per translation. That is fine if it is visible to exactly one translation (i.e. its definition is in your *.m/*.c file). Otherwise, you end up with copies in every translation which includes/imports the header with the static definition. This can result in an inflated binary, as well as an increase to your build times.

B) `const CGRect CGRectOne = {...};` will emit a symbol in the scope it is declared. if that happens to be a header visible to multiple translations you'll end up with link errors (because `CGRectOne` is defined multiple times -- e.g. once per *.c/*.m file which directly or indirectly includes the header where the constant is defined).

Now that you know the context to use those 2 declarations in, let cover the `extern` way. The `extern` way allows you to:

- declare the constant in a header
- use the constant in many translations
- while emitting exactly one definition of the constant

The `extern` approach is ideal for reusing the constant among multiple files. Here's an example:

**File.h**

```
// the declaration in the header:
extern const CGRect CGRectOne;
```

**File.c/m**

```
// the definition:

#import "File.h"

const CGRect CGRectOne = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } };
```

---

Note: Omitting the `const` would just make it a global variable.

Comment: note: technically, you have more options with c++ - i answered as though the question was c/objc.

Comment: This helped me out greatly. Good answer.

Comment: I tried to declare like `extern const CGRect SCREENBOUNDS;` in .h file.. But it is saying `Type name does not allow storage class to be specified`.. you help me to understand this error?

Comment: @Praveen first guess: you have tried to declare the constant inside an `@interface` (or other scope). the extern constant should be declared in the same (global) scope as other extern C declarations (e.g. functions, constants).

Answer (score 21):

There are a couple of options. With C89,

```
const CGRect CGRectOne = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } };
```

With C99,

```
const CGRect CGRectOne = {
    .origin.x = 0.0f,
    .origin.y = 0.0f,
    .size.width = 1.0f,
    .size.height = 1.0f
};
```

or

```
const CGRect CGRectOne = {
    .origin = { .x = 0.0f, .y = 0.0f },
    .size   = { .width = 1.0f, .height = 1.0f }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this

```
static CGRect CGRectOne = (CGRect){.origin.x = 1.0f, .origin.y = 1.0f, .size.width = 1.0f, .size.height = 1.0f};
```

Comment: Does that work? I've never seen that syntax, and I can't get it to compile.

Comment: It's a C99 feature called Compound Literals.

Comment: Ah, I see. Cool. I turned on C99 support using `-std=c99` in "Other C Flags", and now it works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

The technique used here worked well for me: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2612#post-16402

Essentially its the extern method described by Justin, but it provides a pretty full example.

Also, this answer on StackOverflow provides a good example too: [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)