# NSNotifications name best practice

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, nsnotification

In trying to de-couple my model from the view controllers that display fetched data, when an asynchronous fetch completes, I post an NSNotification.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"foobarFetchSuccess" object: foo];
```

I've gotten into the habit of using:

```
 #define FOO_FETCH_SUCCESS  @"foobarFetchSuccess"
```

in a common header file and then using it for the addObserver: and removeObserver: as well as the postNotificationName:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self @selector(gotData)
                                              name:FOO_FETCH_SUCCESS object: baz];
```

So  @"foobarFetchSuccess" string is used all over the place.  And there are many more just like him.
So what's the best way to declare a string once and use it everywhere?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As for using constant strings in your project, there’s another question on Stack Overflow about that: [Constants in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c).

As for naming notifications, [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) suggests the following:

> Notifications are identified by global NSString objects whose names are composed in this way:
>
> `[Name of associated class] + [Did | Will] + [UniquePartOfName] + Notification`

Comment: For the sake of completion, what about the naming convention for the observing selector? According to the [guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF), it's almost the same as the Notification name, minus "Notification" and the class namespace prefix. eq: **windowDidLoad** Is this accurate?

Comment: @pix You can name them at your will. However, if it’s a delegate method that is called because of a notification, then what you’ve said applies — a delegate wouldn’t register for the notification; instead, it’d automatically receive the corresponding message with the notification parameter. Note that `-windowDidLoad` is not really related to a notification (it doesn’t receive an `NSNotification` argument), but the naming convention is similar indeed.

Comment: My gripe with the convention is that names become really long and overall readability is negatively impacted.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't follow the Apple-suggested format exactly, nor does it directly answer your question, but I thought I'd share these handy-dandy text macros that I use to spare myself a little typing when making notification and key names. You can assign these a keyboard shortcut, type in and select the `[Did|Will] + [UniquePartOfName]` segment, then hit the shortcut to produce the variable and its value. You could also use `$(FILENAMEASIDENTIFIER)` instead of `$(PROJECTNAME)` if you were defining these strings in the header of a particular class, and that *would* conform to the suggestion.

```
//MARK: Notification strings
    { /*
       * Use the selection to make the name and string for a Notification.
       * The string has a prefix placeholder, defaulting to the project name.
       */
      Identifier = objc.notestring;
      BasedOn = objc;
      IsMenuItem = YES;
      Name = "Notification Name From Selection";
      TextString = "<#$(PROJECTNAME)#><#!notename!#>Notification = @\"<#$(PROJECTNAME)#><#!notename!#>Notification\";";
      CompletionPrefix = notestring;
    },
    { /*
       * Insert placeholders to make the name and string for a Notification.
       * This is for use without a selection, and so "only" activates at the 
       * beginning of the line.
       */
      Identifier = objc.notestring.bol;
      BasedOn = objc.notestring;
      IsMenuItem = YES;
      Name = "Notification Name From Selection";
      OnlyAtBOL = YES;
      CompletionPrefix = notestring;
    },

//MARK: Default Key strings
    { /*
       * Convert the selection into a name and string for use in the User 
       * Defaults system. The string has a placeholder for a prefix, which
       * defaults to the project name.
       */
      Identifier = objc.defaultskeystring;
      BasedOn = objc;
      IsMenuItem = YES;
      Name = "UserDefaults Key From Selection";
      OnlyAtBOL = NO;
      TextString = "<#$(PROJECTNAME)#><#!keyname!#>Key = @\"<#$(PROJECTNAME)#><#!keyname!#>Key\";";
      CompletionPrefix = defaultskey;
    },
    { /*
       * Insert placeholders to make the name and string for a a key for the
       * User Defaults system. This is for use without a selection, and so 
       * "only" activates at the beginning of the line.
       */
      Identifier = objc.defaultskeystring.bol;
      BasedOn = objc.defaultskeystring;
      IsMenuItem = YES;
      OnlyAtBOL = YES;
      Name = "UserDefaults Key From Selection";
      CompletionPrefix = defaultskey;
    },
```

These are Xcode 3 macros. I know the macro system is different in Xcode 4 (which I'm not using yet), but I believe the conversion is simple and can be automated.