# Where do you declare a constant in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I declared a constant in a header file `const double EARTH_RADIUS=6353;` that is imported to various other headers and I got a linker error.

```
Ld /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.app/BadgerNew normal i386
    cd /Users/Teguh/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/BadgerNew.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.app/BadgerNew

ld: duplicate symbol _EARTH_RADIUS in /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/NearbyIsiKota.o and /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/FrontPageofBadger.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Basically I want the constant to be available for all classes on my project. Where should I declare it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can declare in the header, define it in a code file.  Simply declare it as

```
extern const double EARTH_RADIUS;
```

then in a .m file somewhere (usually the .m for the .h you declared it in)

```
const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6353;
```

Comment: Do you actually need to do the extern in the header ? Without it, it seems to work.

Comment: `extern` in the header allows other files to know about your constant.  If you only need the constant for the scope of a single file, then the `extern` is not necessary.

Comment: in .m, does it matter if before or after `@implementation`?

Comment: @kraftydevil technically it doesn't matter, but the convention is to do it after your `#import`s and before the `@implementation`.  But really anywhere in the global scope of the file is fine (meaning as long as it isn't inside any curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 65):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

**1st option- As previous replies pointed, in the .h file**:

```
myfile.h
extern const int MY_CONSTANT_VARIABLE;
```

and in myfile.m define them

```
myfile.m    
const int MY_CONSTANT_VARIABLE = 5;
```

**2nd option- My favourite**:

```
myfile.h
static const int MY_CONSTANT_VARIABLE = 5 ;
```

Comment: why declare with static const int MY_CONSTANT_VARIABLE = 5  works?

Comment: It works, but only if you need a non global constant. Static constant is not visible outside the file. Otherwise use the 1st option.

Comment: Where in the .h or .m files? Inside curly braces at top? Elsewhere?

Comment: This seems to be wrong. I get the error from Xcode5: "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" when I do `static const int MY_CONSTANT_VARIABLE = 5 ;`

Comment: Hi @learner, are you declaring the constant below the import in your header file?

Answer (score 4):

Declare it in a **source file** and have external linkage to it( using **extern** keyword ) so as to use in all other source files.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to declare it in your .h and .m files. See [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) for a very detailed set of answers regarding this same question.