# Duplicate symbol error in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, linker

I need some globals in my Objective-C application. For that purpose, I've created class Globals (that inherits NSObject) and put readonly properties in it. I've also declared some constants, like this:

```
imports, etc.
.
.
.
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM = -1;
const int other_constants ...
#endif
.
.
.
interface, etc.
```

But when I try to compile it, I get linker error: "Duplicate symbol DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM". Why is that happening, should ifndef prefent it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do you declare constant in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188672/where-do-you-declare-constant-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM = -1;` allocates a int of that name is in every object file you include the header for.
You should only have the declaration `extern const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM;` in each header. The actual value should then be defined `const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM = -1;` in one object file ( ie .m or .c ).

In this case I would just use #define to set the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

In `constants.m`:

```
const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM = -1;
```

In `constants.h`:

```
extern const int DIFFICULTY_CUSTOM;
```

and in the `.pch` file:

```
#import "constants.h"
```