# How do I create constants of type CGSize in header file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, header-files, cgsize

I want to create constants in header file of type `CGSize` so I can use this size anywhere in my app just using `constantName.height` and `constantName.Width`.

I would appreciate if you provide syntax for both cases: 1) fixed height and width, 2) height and width as passing value

Thank you

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188672/where-do-you-declare-a-constant-in-objective-c

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153156/define-vs-const-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed height and width

1. `#define MAXSIZE CGSizeMake(320, 480)`

For passing values, you can give the value MySizeType i.e defined as CGSize. But for Constant why do you want to pass values.

2. `typedef CGSize MySizeType;`

**EDIT**

After few comments not to use Macros I am elaborating my answer over here.

Using MACROS the drawback is that your debugger cannot know the constant.

And also there more ways to create a constant depends on the scope of your constant you want,

1. For internal class only

`static CGSize const MAXSIZE = {320, 480};`

2. For outside class

In .h file

```
extern CGSize const MAXSIZE;
```

In .m file

```
CGSize const MAXSIZE = {320,480};
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I actually need constant value. I just wanted to know if in future I need to create any object(not constant) in header file which accepts passing value from different class.

Comment: I couldn't get your point regarding MACRO drawback. Can you please elaborate that in easy language? And the edited solution you gave me is not applicable to write in header files. I usually use header files for globally used variables. thanks

Comment: I do not want to initialise this constant value everytime in every .m file. I want it to be with fixed value written in a single file (global header file). So that I just need to import this file and use the variable.

Comment: I can do this using #define kSize CGSizeMake(13.0f, 34.0f) in header file. But some are saying that it has drawback if we use macro.

Comment: I have mentioned that define is not debugger friendly

Comment: Nice hack with {320,480}, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer.

**1) Fixed**

```
#define kSize CGSizeMake(13.0f, 34.0f)
```

**2) Pass value**

```
#define kSize(width, height) CGSizeMake(width, height)
```

You can use like this

```
CGSize size = kSize(12.0f,12.0f);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```

Comment: @Sulthan what is wrong in using macros for this need?