# Linking External Constants -- Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, constants, extern

In [an earlier answer about external constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c), the preferred answer says

> "Constants.m should be added to your application/framework's target so
>   that it is linked in to the final product."

I am using Xcode 4 and can't see how this is done. Can someone help me with this?

I'm trying to move my user interface constants to a single file so I can manage them from one place. (I'm not interested in using a singleton for this case.)

---

Based on the answer provided below, I was able to make this work. The .h and .m files are very simple:

Constants.h

```
#pragma mark - Calendar Settings
extern const CGSize _kTileSize;
```

Constants.m

```
#import "Constants.h"

#pragma mark - Calendar Settings
const CGSize _kTileSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

Note that there is no interface and no implementation, Since it is not a class. I did add the files as instructed in the answer, except I selected new file... objective c class. Then I deleted the interface and implementation sections.

Now that I have it working I will add more constants to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Go as follow:**

1.File

2.New

3.New file

4.Objective C file

Answer (score 0):

File -> New -> New file -> Objective C file.

Comment: I tried this, but I don't see that choice. I see "objective c class" as a choice. I may be more confused by this than I thought. I'll post my two files in my original question.

Comment: Your answer works. I didn't realize it until I found my real problem. It was a typo. For future reference, I'll post .h and .m files. Thanks. (And since you posted first, I will select your response as the correct one.)