# Error linking constants to pch in Objective-C XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to [link up some constants to my iOS app in XCode as per the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c).  I created a Constants.h header file like this:

```
//  Constants.h
//  myApp

extern NSString * const tumblrConsumerKey;
extern NSString * const tumblrConsumerSecret;
```

and a Constants.m implementation file like this:

```
//  Constants.m
//  myApp

#import "Constants.h"
NSString * const tumblrConsumerKey = @"keyiskey";
NSString * const tumblrConsumerSecret = @"secret";
```

I then added this to the top of my myApp-Prefix.pch precompiled header:

```
// Prefix header for all source files of the 
// 'myApp' target in the 'myApp' project
//
#import <Availability.h>
#import "Constants.h"
```

Now I'm getting an error in the Constants.h file at the lines that declare `extern NSString * const` etc:

```
Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 
'*' token in /Users/me/Documents/iPhone Programs/myApp/myApp/Constants.h
```

It looks like my Constants.m file has been added to the target for myApp.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't `extern const NSString *tumblrConsumerKey`?

Comment: It would appear that `NSString` is not being recognized as a type.  Or, perhaps, some spurious characters prior to that are confusing things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are being a bit eager with the placement of your include. It should be after the other frameworks

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

Also it's good practice to start constants with capital letters, normally 2-3 letters abbreviation of your name/company. It makes it easier to see you are dealing with a constant and not just a normal variable.

**References:**

Apple's recomendations on [prefixing names](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226-BBCJECED)

Apple's recommendations for declaring [constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001783)