# #define macros and xcode warning and lack of code hinting

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macros, categories

I wrote up some small macros to help in setting application-wide font styles, colors and gradients. The issue is that xcode is throwing warnings whenever I use the color or font defined in the macro. Is there any way to get xcode to validate the macro, and hopefully get code hinting as well?

```
#define HEX_COLOR(colorname, hexcolor) \
\
@implementation UIColor(Style##colorname) \
\
+ (UIColor*) colorname \
{ \
    static UIColor * staticColor = nil; \
    if(! staticColor) { \
        float red   = ((hexcolor & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0; \
        float green = ((hexcolor & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0; \
        float blue  = (hexcolor & 0xFF)/255.0; \
        float alpha = (hexcolor >> 24)/255.0; \
        \
        staticColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:red \
                                       green:green \
                                        blue:blue \
                                       alpha:alpha] retain]; \
    } \
    return  staticColor; \
} \
@end
```

In my app delegate i set the application-wide fonts and colors like this:

```
HEX_COLOR(specialGreenColor, 0x66BAD455);
.....
```

This line throws the warning that the property might not exist.

```
[[UIColor specialGreenColor] set];
```

Also I do not want to lessen the error reporting in xcode as not seeing warning is a backwards step. I just would like to find a way to regiester the marco with xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code hinting for the marco works in xCode 4.2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define constants, you should use `#define` like so:

```
#define COLOUR_NAME 0x66BAD455
```

Then, the preprocessor will go through your file and replace all instances of `COLOUR_NAME` *verbatim* with `0x66BAD455`.

There are arguably [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) to define application-wide constants though.

Edit: there's also [this nice post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7162805#7162805) which seems to provide a better implementation of what you're going for. You can define the macro and then define your colour constants using the question linked above.