# How to declare enum to pass from one object to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, enums

I have two objects: NavButton, visible on each ViewController and a particular ViewController. NavButton should know, which kind of ViewController is asking for it and hide unneeded buttons. I consider implementing this as passing an enum from ViewController to NavButton.
I have two questions on this:
1. Where should I declare enum?
2. How to make enum visible in all of the ViewControllers, so, each VC could access NavButton's property as: `self.navButton.kind = bigButton;`

Comment: Put the enum in a .h file that each view controller can import.

Comment: What template should I use to create that .h file? As usual class? Is it OK to put that file to prefix.pch?

Comment: Template? You don't need a template. Just a clean .h file with the enum.

Comment: And is it OK to put in prefix?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912222/objective-c-typedef-enum-in-global-constants-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the C header template + the nsenum macro expansion and voila!

```
//
//  Header.h
//  Test
//
//  Created by Yours Truly on 8/7/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Adam Christopher Smith. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef Test_Header_h
#define Test_Header_h

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyEnum) {
    MyEnumValueA,
    MyEnumValueB,
    MyEnumValueC,
};

#endif
```

If I have a lot of these and they are used by different parts of the app, I tend to stick quite a few into one file (maybe, Types.h) and put that into my pch. Quite acceptable IMO.

Comment: And how can I define a property of this enum in object?

Comment: @property (nonatomic) MyEnum myEnumValue;