# How to Use Constant String Variables in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I created `Constants.h` and `Constants.m` as suggested here:

[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Now I want to also use some strings defined in `Constants.h` in Interface Builder to for example set the text of a label.

How to do this using bindings? I think I should somehow use an ObjectController (Mode: Class, Class Name: Constants)? But what would be the Content Object for this controller (since I don't have any variable of type Constants)? Maybe use a Singleton in `Constants.m`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can bind the strings in any way.

I would recommend do it in code in `viewDidLoad`.

Note that string constants aren't so great for texts in UI.

EDIT:

Xibs have their own localization system but I don't think it's very good. It basically means creating a new xib for every language. If you support only one language, just put your strings into the xib and the problem is solved.

NOTE: the following is an idea for my current project and I haven't implemented it yet but I suppose it would let us easily add new language translations.

My idea for a better xib localization is to define IBOutlet for every localizable component (e.g. myButton1, myTextField1) and then write a file with localized strings (xml, properties, plist whatever) where every string is keyed by the IBOutlet name, e.g:

```
   myXib1.myButton1.selected.title = This is a button.
   myXib1.myTextField1.placeholder = "This is text field placeholder"
```

Then, you have to write a method which takes the xib name, finds current language and goes through all string properties for the given xib. It can use `[NSObject performSelector:]` to access the IBOutlet getters:

`id localizableView = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"myButton1")];`

and you call this method from `viewDidLoad` (or you create a UILocalizedController class which calls it automatically and all your controllers will be its descendant).

Also note there is `NSLocalizedString` class which should help you with localization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think would be a better way? Using the constants as keys to strings stored in a .strings file? Any other idea to not set the strings programmatically?

Comment: Answer updated. In short, if you have only one language, forget about constants and put everything into a xib. If you are thinking about i18n, read the extended answer.