# Do you use constants when working with NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I understand using constants for your names in a NSDictionary to prevent typos (myName will auto complete vs @"myName" won't).

i'm working with a medium size dictionaries right now and a couple of times, i've misstyped key names and had to spend some time tracking down where i miss spelled a word.

i'm wondering, do you consider it worth while to set up a constants naming scheme?

Comment: Yes, if you use them a lot. It also makes refactoring (err, renaming the keys) easier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, but I'd advise defining proper string constants rather than #defines for your strings because string constants are type-safe and every reference will use the same actual string object, which improves the performance of using `isEqualToString:` to compare them.

To define a private string constant you can put this in your .m file:

```
static NSString *const MyConstant = @"MyConstant";
```

To make it public, you can either put this in your .h file instead, or you can split the definition by putting this in your .h:

```
extern NSString *const MyConstant;
```

And this in your .m file:

```
NSString *const MyConstant = @"MyConstant";
```

Comment: +1 very good answer and totally the way to go -- hopefully this will be read by some of my coworkers who are constantly using defines for those things; thunder and lightning shall hit them on the toilet!

Answer (score 4):

I usually create a GlobalDefinitions.h file and place macros that I can use in code instead of magic strings.

.h file

```
#define PERSON_NAME @"Person_name"
#define PERSON_BDAY @"Person_bday"
```

By including the .h file you can now access you values like so

```
[dictionary objectForKey:PERSON_NAME];
```

Comment: Note that constant string are better than #def'd strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c

Comment: Agreed - see my answer below for how to define string constants.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's worth it.
Consistency in something like this does what you say: it cuts down on errors and saves you time.