# how to declare constants in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to declare two different constants in my app
one is a simple string, the other needs to be a uint32.

I know of two different ways to declare constants as follows

```
#define VERSION 1; //I am not sure how this works in regards to uint32.. but thats what I need it to be.
```

and

```
NSString * const SIGNATURE = @"helloworld";
```

is there a way to do the version which should be a uint32 like the nsstring decliration below?

for instance something like

```
UInt32 * const VERSION 1;
```

if so how? if not, how do i make sure the #define version is of type uint32?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: would [this related, potentially duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) have the answer you're looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constants in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close. The correct syntax is:

```
const UInt32 VERSION = 1;
```

You can also use `UInt32 const` rather than `const UInt32`. They're identical for scalars. For pointers such as `SIGNATURE`, however, the order matters, and your order is correct.

Comment: cool, thanks very much for that, I will mark your answer once the time is up for doing so. pretty much that explains why I was getting the pointer error because I was using the *... damn i hate pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused by macro definitions & constants:

```
#define VERSION (1)
```

or

```
#define SOME_STRING @"Hello there"
```

The above are macro definitions. This means during compilation VERSION & SOME_STRING will be replaced with the defined values all over the code. This is a quicker solution, but is more difficult to debug.

Examples of constant declarations are:

```
const NSUInteger VERSION = 1;
NSString * const RKLICURegexException = @"Some string";
```

Look at the constants like simple variables that are immutable and can't change their values.

Also, be careful with defining pointers to constants & constant values.