# NSNotificationCenter is not working?

Tags: objective-c

as i told here i am using `NSNotificationCenter` .

on **class A** (observer) on the init method i have got :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getSensorsData:) name:@"HotSpotTouched" object:nil];
```

on **classB** i have got :

```
//FILL NSDICTIONARY WITH DATA
    [dict setObject:@"SPOT1" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    [dict setObject:@"SPOT2" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
    [dict setObject:@"SPOT3" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
    [dict setObject:@"SPOT4" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:3]];
    [dict setObject:@"SPOT5" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:4]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HotSpotTouched" object:dict];
```

the function in  class A `getSensorsData` is not being called.

whats wrong here ??

thanks !

Comment: what does your declaration for `getSensorsData` look like?  is it in your `.h` interface file?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : -(void)getSensorsData:(NSNotification *)SPOTS

Comment: That declaration looks potentially wrong.  Edit your question to show your declaration and how you're accessing your `NSDictionary` within `getSensorsData`.  Are you setting a breakpoint and is it not hitting when the notification fires?  Is classB happening on a different thread?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved:

**if you passing a null argument, the observer is not getting the call !**

my `NSDictionary` argument was null( because a reason i still dont know), so the call is not fired.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You are passing in `dict` as `notificationSender` when posting the notification, and `nil` when you add the observer. This way your notification is filtered out because the senders mismatch.</strike>

**Update:**
As pointed out by joerick in the comments, passing nil when adding an observer will disable sender filtering. So this isn't the problem here.

I just created a small sample project and for me notifications are delivered.

@Rant: If you want to pass arbitrary data along with your notification, you should use the userInfo dictionary (as pointed out by Cyrille in the comment).

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking, too.

Comment: You want to post `dict` as the `userData`, not the `object` of your `NSNotification`.

Comment: passing `nil` for `addObserver:...` means all notifications are observed, regardless of sender. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: couldnt understand you, so i have to change nil to dict ? but the other class dont know dict..

Comment: @weichsel i have change to:     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HotSpotTouched" object:self userInfo:dict]; still no luck

Comment: i have seen that the fact that i put oserver on the init, its the problem and that i have to put it on the initWithStyle ???

Answer (score 3):

The calls to the notification center look correct. I suspect the problem is due to the liffe cycle of object A. You say that you're registering for the notification in the `init` method. Have you correctly assigned `self`?:

```
-(id)init
{
    //self does not have a meaningful value prior to the call to [super init]
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        //ensure addObserver is called in the if code block
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, it's good practice to use constants for notification names as they mitigate against typos. See [Constants in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i do : -(id) init
{if( (self=[super init])) ....    is that ok ?

Comment: I also tried exactly as you said and it prints the nslog under the if statement.