# How to print out string constant with NSLog on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, string, constants, nslog

I have a string constant defined like this:

```
#define kMyString @"This is my string text!";
```

Somewhere in the code I would like to print-out this piece of code with NSLog like that:

```
NSLog(@"This is it: %@",kMyString);
```

But get a build error: `Expected expression`.

I have already looked at the Apple's [Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) but could not figured it out.

Can someone please explain it to me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should remove `;` from the definition of `kMyString`:

```
#define kMyString @"This is my string text!"
```

The way you did it is equivalent to:

```
NSLog(@"This is it: %@", @"This is my string text!";);
```

Comment: I have mistyped in question. But the problem still exists.

Comment: OMG. Actually I have mistyped also in code. Removed semicolon and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`%@` is for objects. `BOOL` is not an object.
On the bases of data type `%@` changes as follows

```
For Strings you use %@
For int  you use %i
For float you use %f
For double you use %lf
```

Comment: There are no BOOLs mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Remove that semi colon after `#define` and use `%@` and it will work.

Comment: well if you want a string constant you can always use 'extern NSString * const MyFirstConstant;'

Comment: refer this link I think this is what you want.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/919545

Comment: I know about that but I prefer #define like constants. BTW I just solved the problem - looked at the answer by @sch