# Objective-C Equivalent of Ruby Symbols

Tags: objective-c, ruby, symbols

In Ruby, we have symbols to use for the key of hashes. I'm trying to port a Ruby library to Objective-C, and the library has a hash in it that uses symbols as keys. Is there any similar soulution for Objective-C? Or should I be using `NSString`s?

Comment: Objective-C is a super-set of C, so you might be able to use `#define` constants to achieve a similar outcome.

Comment: call a to_s on all the symbols, and you have strings available to use as your keys (symbols are mutable strings)

Comment: I;m talking about symbols in Objective-C, not Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDictionary` keys in Objective-C are usually `NSString`s. That's probably the way to go here.

You don't have to worry about Ruby string literals vs. symbols; just create an `NSString` with the string value for the key or use a literal `@"my key name"` string as required.

Comment: @benalpert 's answer is the better answer. The use of a symbol is idiomatic in Ruby because they are immutable and are only created once. In Objective-C a const pointer to a string is the equivalent that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen declarations like

```
extern NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeNewKey = @"NSKeyValueChangeNewKey";
```

so that you can use it as a key:

```
[dict objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
```

For an explanation that's a bit more detailed, see [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c).

Comment: Search for `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`

Comment: Thanks, just found a nice SO answer explaining it.

Comment: For the record: Please don't prefix your constants with "NS" — that's Apple's prefix.

Comment: @Chuck: Sorry, I was trying to pseudo-quote from Apple source code. I'll change to hmt's example to be a bit more clear.