# Is There a Way to Declare Constant in Objective C without Using Extern

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

The issue is like this:
[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

So we declare the constant once in .h files and set it's value in .m

Is there a way to declare constant and define it at the same time?

I mean real constant, not macro (though macro is fine too, and it's faster anyway, and has no disadvantage anyway)

Comment: I know about macro. That is not real constant. I guess, there is no other way.

Comment: So look like the answer is you can't define and declare constant in .h at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
#define MY_CONSTANT 9
```

Comment: That's macro, not true constant :D

Answer (score 2):

hope this will work

```
  #define MY_VALUE 165.0
```

Comment: Dude your answer is exactly the same with the other guy and it really should be #. Very well, I am point source. Cool. +1