# How can I use a String in more than one file?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

in my view controller.m i have a string like this

```
 NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
```

and would like to safe the text with NSUserDefauls in Appdelegate.m

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
 setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

how can i use the NSString in the other file? 
This doesn't work:

```
#import "viewcontroller.m";
```

Comment: Same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c/539191#539191).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a header file have `extern NSString *valueToSave;`. Then in a (1 and only 1) .m file have `NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";`

---

A second option would be to use a #define. Simply put `#define kValueToSave (@"someValue")` in a header file and use it where you need it.