# Xcode: I just got an Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error and don't know why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS Development, I'm using the latest version of Xcode and just got an error that said Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error exit code 1 and I haven't got a clue why. I think this is relevant but I'm not sure what it means:

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Timing1ViewController in /Users/tomkenning/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EggTimer-ciznfdheqrtybuavrtbbcxfywyyw/Build/Intermediates/EggTimer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EggTimer.build/Objects-normal/i386/Mediumhb.o and /Users/tomkenning/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EggTimer-ciznfdheqrtybuavrtbbcxfywyyw/Build/Intermediates/EggTimer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EggTimer.build/Objects-normal/i386/Timing1ViewController.o for architecture i386

All I've done recently is initialise and set some integer values in a .m file and then link to them from .h file from another ViewController, using #import "suchandsuch.m", there's been no errors in the code, but is that not allowed?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this:

```
#import "suchandsuch.m"
```

Do this:

```
#import "suchandsuch.h"
```

You are probably compiling `suchandsuch.m`, which defines the class `Timing1ViewController`, normally (by including `suchandsuch.m` in your target's list of files to build).  Then your `#import "suchandsuch.m"` causes that same code to be inserted into a different source file, which is compiled as well. The result: two different source files try to define `Timing1ViewController`.

To do your constants the right way -- by declaring them `extern` in `suchandsuch.h` and defining them in `suchandsuch.m` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/1218876).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two `Timing1ViewController` classes with the same name. If you don't try to Product -> Clean and build again.