# How to declare and use NSString global constants

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Constants in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

I store some app settings in NSUserDefaults. NSStrings are used as keys. The problem is I need to access these settings throughout the app using those NSString keys. There is a chance that I mistype such string key when accessing in some part of the app.

Throughout the app, I have such statements

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ReminderSwitch"];

BOOL shouldRemind = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ReminderSwitch"];
```

How and where can I declare a global NSString constant which I can access throughout the app. I will then be able to use that constant without worrying about mistyping those string keys.

Answer (score 14):

First, you should go for a real extern C symbol -- not a macro. this is done like so:

SomeFile.h

```
extern NSString *const MONConstantString;
```

SomeFile.m

```
NSString *const MONConstantString = @"MONConstantString";
```

note that if you use a mix of ObjC and ObjC++, you will need to specify `extern "C"` for C++ TUs -- that's why you will see a `#define`d export which varies by language.

---

Then, you will want to put the constant near the interfaces it relates to. Taking your example as a lead, you might want a set of interfaces or declarations for your app's preferences. In that case, you might add the declaration to `MONAppsPreferences` header:

MONAppsPreferences.h

```
extern NSString *const MONApps_Pref_ReminderSwitch;
```

MONAppsPreferences.m

```
NSString *const MONApps_Pref_ReminderSwitch = @"MONApps_Pref_ReminderSwitch";
```

---

In use:

```
#import "MONAppsPreferences.h"
...
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:MONApps_Pref_ReminderSwitch];
```

Answer (score 9):

Your thought is right I think. For example, I made Const.h/m file like below:

**Const.h**

```
extern NSString *const UserIdPrefKey;
extern NSString *const PasswordPrefKey;
extern NSString *const HomepagePrefKey;
```

**Const.m**

```
#import "AEConst.h"

NSString *const UserIdPrefKey = @"UserIdPrefKey";
NSString *const PasswordPrefKey = @"PasswordPrefKey";
NSString *const HomepagePrefKey = @"UrlHomepagePrefKey";
```

Only Const.h must be imported.

When you write code, Xcode supports writing the key name so that you can avoid miss-typing.

Answer (score 5):

What you seem to be looking for is just a way to define string constants in your app.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)
and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/27615) to it, which I've quoted below:

> You should create a header file like
>
> ```
> // Constants.h 
> FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MyFirstConstant;
> FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MySecondConstant;
> //etc.
> ```
>
> You can include this file in each file that uses the constants or in the pre-compiled header > for the project.
>
> You define these constants in a .m file like
>
> ```
> // Constants.m 
> NSString *const MyFirstConstant = @"FirstConstant";
> NSString *const MySecondConstant = @"SecondConstant";
> ```
>
> Constants.m should be added to your application/framework's target so that it is linked in to the final product.
>
> The advantage of using string constants instead of #define'd constants
>   is that you can test for equality using pointer comparison
>   `(stringInstance == MyFirstConstant)` which is much faster than string
>   comparison `([stringInstance isEqualToString:MyFirstConstant])` (and
>   easier to read, IMO).

With thanks to Barry Wark :)

Comment: he just wants the constants in the app (internal linkage) so I'm wondering why you are suggesting he export them(external linkage)?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is make simple .h file, like Utils.h  and write there following code:

`#define kUserDefaults @"ReminderSwitch"`

Comment: yeah, not so safe, there is a chance for some other objective c file to override that without getting noticed :(