# Unable to read NSString * const in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, constants, exc-bad-access

In my header file, I declared

```
extern NSString * const UserDefault_ClusterItemWidth;
```

And in my implement file I gave it a value

```
NSString * const UserDefault_ClusterItemWidth = @"ClusterItemWidth";
```

Everything seems right, but when I called it

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0.0f forKey:UserDefault_ClusterItemWidth];
```

I got

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fb1b700)
```

and XCode show something like this when I place the mouse on top of the constant

```
(NSString *const) UserDefault_ClusterItemWidth = 0x0000000100c1c698
```

Instead of @"ClusterItemWidth"

I am running out of idea on what is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Most probably you have to use `@interface` and `@implementation` sections to declare and define Objective-C objects

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Thanks for your comment. However, I believe that is not the case here, because the constant is a Global constant. From what I know, you declare the constant in `.h file` and give it a value in the `.m file`. No need of `@interface` or `@implementation`. Here is an example : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932969/how-to-declare-and-use-nsstring-global-constants].

Comment: @KwokPingLau I think problem is from another place. Nothing happens when creating a new project with your above code.

Comment: @trungduc thx, I will definitely take a closer look. But so far, no luck.

Comment: @trungduc Thx again, yes, you are right. Apparently I accidentally created an infinite loop.

Comment: Interesting, the following code seems so good, how does it crash? could you paste the crash stack info out? The two pointer addresses you mentioned are different, I believe that crash must happen in the other place.

Comment: @Itachi Actually it doesn't show anything other than `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fb1b700)`. Also, yes, it occurred in other place. I call the NSUserDefaults infinite time by accident, so the app just crushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, I have accidentally created an infinite loop, setting the NSUserDefaults over and over again and causes the app to crush.

Comment: Good job, So set this answer as an accepted answer then.

Comment: @JoeRazon Thx ^^. But it seems I can only accept it tomorrow, there is a duration before I can accept the answer.