# which one is better Macro or String Constants?

Tags: ios, macros, constants

I have confused which way I have to use for "seenArray" 
`#define kseenArray     @"seenArray"` and `NSString * const kseenArray = @"seenArray";`Why?.In respect to memory ,if any, I want to know about it which one is better.

Comment: i did not get you.by and??

Comment: Please explain how you want to use this "constant"

Comment: Try both and compare the assembly. I expect there will be very little difference

Comment: For any 'NSDictionary' i have to give some "key" for that key i want one of the way which i have mentioned in above.

Comment: @JamesWebster , Please explain about compare assembly.

Comment: I've written an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know enough about Assembly to make a conclusion, I've written the test and provided the results, I'll let you reach your own conclusion

I wrote this little test:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString * const aString = @"String";
//#define aString @"String"
int main()
{
    NSLog(@"%@", aString);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with the line:

```
gcc StringTest.m -g -m64 -framework Cocoa
```

---

This first assembly uses `#define`

```
0x0000000100000ee0 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000ee1 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000ee4 <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000ee8 <main+8>:    lea    0x191(%rip),%rax        # 0x100001080
0x0000000100000eef <main+15>:   lea    0x16a(%rip),%rcx        # 0x100001060
0x0000000100000ef6 <main+22>:   xor    %dl,%dl
0x0000000100000ef8 <main+24>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000000100000efb <main+27>:   mov    %rcx,%rsi
0x0000000100000efe <main+30>:   mov    %dl,%al
0x0000000100000f00 <main+32>:   callq  0x100000f22 <dyld_stub_NSLog>
0x0000000100000f05 <main+37>:   movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f0c <main+44>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f0f <main+47>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f12 <main+50>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f15 <main+53>:   add    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000f19 <main+57>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000100000f1a <main+58>:   retq
```

This assembly uses `NSString * const`

```
0x0000000100000ee0 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000ee1 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000ee4 <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000ee8 <main+8>:    mov    0x171(%rip),%rax        # 0x100001060 <aString>
0x0000000100000eef <main+15>:   lea    0x192(%rip),%rcx        # 0x100001088
0x0000000100000ef6 <main+22>:   xor    %dl,%dl
0x0000000100000ef8 <main+24>:   mov    %rcx,%rdi
0x0000000100000efb <main+27>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
0x0000000100000efe <main+30>:   mov    %dl,%al
0x0000000100000f00 <main+32>:   callq  0x100000f22 <dyld_stub_NSLog>
0x0000000100000f05 <main+37>:   movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f0c <main+44>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f0f <main+47>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f12 <main+50>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f15 <main+53>:   add    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000f19 <main+57>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000100000f1a <main+58>:   retq
```

Comment: It seems same for both way!!

Comment: Then there is your answer. There isn't (enough / any) difference.

Comment: And what about multiple object files referencing the same string literal?

Comment: There's a new test for you to do @Sandy. Try the same test with multiple object files referencing the same string literal. Same procedure, then compare the assembly

Answer (score 2):

In terms of memory I don't think it will make much difference as the compiler won't make a copy of the string literal, and will make all references to the same object.

However I think this is best:

```
NSString * const kseenArray = @"seenArray";
```

As it allows you do to compare the literal based on the *address* of the object, rather than its content (using `[NSString isEqualToString]`), which is faster:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)someString
{
    if (someString == kseenArray)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Also look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

const string is better.

Macro keeps copy blindly. So it actually creates the string object when you are using the macro.

However putting const will only refer to the global string.

Answer (score 0):

Macro substitution happens on compile time. Hence if you use the macro 1000x in your code, it's the same as coding 1000 copy of the same string literal

With const variable, if you reference it 1000 times, you are still referencing the same one.

Comment: do you want to say both are same?

Comment: Depends on how the compiler treats it. Smart compiler might notice you have 1000 immutable string literals scattered everywhere and optimizes it. With reference to const variable you're more likely to not have duplication