# Where to store strings for iOS app

Tags: objective-c

I have an iOS app that requires me to have a "bank" of multiple strings. What I mean is that I need to have several strings that I can call upon at any time. Here is what I am thinking of.

```
// Strings.h
#define STR_ONE @"1"
#define STR_TWO @"2"
// ...
```

And when I need to use these strings, I simply include the header file. I chose to go with a header file because there will be many of these strings, and I just wanted to keep them separate.
So the question: **Is this the best approach to solve my problem? Are there any alternate (and better) ways that I am missing?**

Side notes: Is there any memory management I need to be thinking about here?
            Should this be written to a file, and drawn upon from there?

Thankyou

Comment: What you are doing is fine but use constants instead of defines.

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**NSArray:** you can store a fixed amount of string insiden an array

> NSArray* nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jill Valentine", @"Peter Griffin", @"Meg Griffin"

**NSMutableArray:** this type of array can expand and decrease in size.

> NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> [self.names addObject:@"Harry Potter"];

**If** the amount of Strings is not enorm, a simple Plist will work for you. But i also would recommend you to read about core data.

***[Property List Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)***

Comment: I think he just wants to know where to place those #define strings.

Comment: why would he use an array ;) he has N constant strings