# Is there a way to import implementation file (.m) in another implementation file in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My problem is that I am declaring some strings, arrays.... in an implementation file, and I wanna a kind of include (like in PHP) to avoid declaration errors...

For example in the code bellow **coordi** (see the end of the last line) an NSString which is declared in another implementation file, in my code now, xCode is giving me an error saying that **coordi** is not declared, however it is declared in another implementation file.

> ```
> - (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {   
>    if (_searchQuery.text.length < 3 ) {
>     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No destination !" message:@"Please enter a destination !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
>     [alert show];
> } else {
> [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seg_map" sender:self];
>     NSString *query = [[self.searchQuery text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@"\%20"];       
>     NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", coordi, query]]; }}
> ```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the header file of the .m file where your coordi variable has been defined, you have to do the declaration.

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *coordi; // Can use extern if mixing with C++
```

and in your implementation file you can do

```
NSString *coordi= @"myString";
```

now whereever you include the header you will have access to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare this as a const string. Then in a .h file you should specify the const using the extern specifier. This will make it available to any files the import that .h file.

This is better answered here:
[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Comment: Can you please explain according to my case ? because I've tried the solutions on the link you provided, but it seems that they are not working for me.

Comment: seems @BKC beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll assume the `coordi` variable is in a class called `YourClass`)

Create the `coordi` variable as `static`, just bellow your `@implementation YourClass`, like this

```
static NSString *coordi;
```

in YourClass.h

create a method with a `+` instead of a `-` (These works like static methods):

```
+ (void)setCoordiString:(NSString*)string;
```

in YourClass.m

```
    + (void)setCoordiString:(NSString*)string{
         coordi = string;
    }
```

Now, in whatever class you want to set YourClass's coordi string just do this:

First, import `YourClass.h`:

```
#import "YourClass.h"
```

Then this code right in the moment you want to set coordi:

```
[YourClass setCoordiString:@"Your String Here!"];
```

Hope it helped!