# Correct place to define Constants?

Tags: objective-c, constants

where is the right place to define contants in an Xcode project?
Such as an URL, that wont change or some images for a different backgroundstyle.
AppDelegate.h? If so, where exactly? I'd like to create clean code.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language are you using? The "clean" version will vary slightly from language to language.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I thought the Xcode-Keyword will do. Its Objective-C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constants in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about you create a header file, probably `constants.h` and define your constants in it, for example

```
#define URL_WEBSERVICE @"http://..."
#define COLOR_TEXT [UIColor colorWithRed:.75 green:1.0 blue:.4 alpha:1.0]
#define MAX_RESULTS 100
```

You can also import this header file into your precompiled header file `.pch` so that the values in it become visible to all your files.

Comment: If these constants are to be globally visible then this is a perfectly fine solution. If they are specific to a source file, then they should probably just be defined at the top of the source file. If you want them to be visible to any code using a class, then they should be defined in the header file for the class.

Comment: I like this way of fixing the problem. Very clean! Thanks! I voted.