# Is it possible to have Swift & Objective-C code in the same file?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, swift

For instance in this big project I'm working on there is a "global" header file with #Defines to URLs. I cant use those in swift, but for clarity I want to have the swift alternative in the same .h file so if one is ever changed it should be obvious to change the other.

I was hoping with some compiler magic, this might be possible.

Comment: [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html)

Comment: [Interacting with Objective C API's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use #define -- instead use constants.

[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

You can access Objective-C constants from Swift (using a bridging header)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You can use them in the same project though.

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps)

Comment: ah bummer, I've looked through the apple docs and didn't find anything related to my question, so I wasn't too hopeful