# Declaring NSString constants

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

Right now I am using the following way declare constants in header file:

```
static NSString *const RSMaxNumberOfIndustiresKey = @"MaxNumberOfIndustries";
```

Is it correct? I read [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c?rq=1) question but I really don't know if I really need to declare constant in 2 different places using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You should use the following in `Constants.h`:

```
extern NSString *const RSMaxNumberOfIndustiresKey;
```

and this in `Constants.m`:

```
NSString *const RSMaxNumberOfIndustiresKey = @"MaxNumberOfIndustries";
```

(i.e. add an implementation file simply to hold the single instance of the string constants).

Using your current method means there is a copy of each string within every file that includes that header.

Comment: String literals are not copied in memory in Objective-C.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yeah it's not the end of the world with string constants, but once other types of objects are used, it will become a problem.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You will have a variable collision once you import the header from two different places.