# comparing NSString vs NSString * const (on iOS8.1) fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8.1

I want to log some errors generated when using a WebView. For instance:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSString * domain;
    domain  = [error domain];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    if ( domain == NSURLErrorDomain ) {NSLog(@"log me");}
}
```

I found this does not work on Xcode 6.1 and iOS8.1-simulator. 
It used to work on previous iOS versions (tested with Xcode 6.1 and iOS7-simulator).
**What am I missing?**

Here is the console output:

> 2014-11-06 03:42:15.295 MyApp debug[21897:3606481] Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7a7531c0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.google.fr/}

And some debugging when using the iOS8-simulator:

> (lldb) p NSURLErrorDomain (void *)
>   $0 = 0x0064dacc
>   (lldb) po domain
>   NSURLErrorDomain
>
> (lldb) p domain 
>   (NSString *) $2 = 0x0064dacc @"NSURLErrorDomain"

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Aaron's answer: What you were doing was always wrong, but it may have worked because of an accident about the way Cocoa stores strings. `domain == NSURLErrorDomain` tests whether these are effectively one and the same *object*. Well, maybe under some conditions they are; Cocoa may sometimes behave efficiently by treating two different instances of, say, the literal `@"howdy"` as references to one and the same object. But clearly it makes no sense to *count* on that behavior. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Even if both strings are in theory the "same" constant, from the same class, there may be two copies of the constant, in two different modules.  This possibility makes the use of `==` flakier still.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're comparing strings, you're going to want to use `isEqualToString:` like so:

```
if ( [domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain] ) {NSLog(@"log me");}
```

Comment: My understanding is that it should work also (comparing pointers). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c/539191#539191

Comment: I had the same issue in my app, actually.  Previously it was working fine but recently ceased to work, and `isEqualToString:` fixed it up since it's (obviously) a surefire way to compare the strings.  `matt` gave a more thorough explanation as well.

Comment: I agree with what you and matt says. Comparing 2 strings must be done with 'isEqualToString'. My intention when doing 'domain == NSURLErrorDomain' was to compare the pointers. And, according to the LLDB output they are pointing to the same address. Right?