# updated advice on setting constants in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I read through the advice here [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c), but I find two errors in the accepted answer:

1. I keep getting linker errors when I implement the approach of using .m and .h
2. In my constants.m file, I get the error "unknown type" for NSString

   I am also getting an error following the advice from @VictorHanHee
   as a further suggestion of how to link the constants to a .pch file:
3. I don't have a .pch file by default, and when I create a new one it
   doesn't have the formatting expected from the answer.

All I have done is create constants.h and constants.m and put the constant declarations in them as provided in the accepted answer. I also created a .pch file, but as I said it doesn't at all match VictorHanHee's description.

Is this older posting outdated, or if not what am I missing? I don't really know how to go forward with a linker error. I simply want to have a file constants.h where I declare all constants and can include this file in as many classes as I want to make life easier. Can someone tell me how to do this nowadays or point to a more recent discussion?

Also here is the linker error (or part of log I can copy and paste anyway, not full message)

```
    -[AccountInfoViewController viewDidLoad] in AccountInfoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As you can see, I am trying to access the constant from viewDidLoad. I am simply trying to print it out with NSLog.

Here are the .h and .m files I was originally using:

.h

```
extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT;
```

.m

```
NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant";
```

Ok here is the template that actually seems to work:

.h

```
#ifndef Project_prefs_h
#define Project_prefs_h


#endif


extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT;
```

.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant";
```

So the older post is perhaps misleading or I misunderstood them when they said remove everything apart from the constants - but if you don't actually want to remove everything, shouldn't you say so? That's a fair amount of text in there not to mention...

Comment: "I get the error "unknown type" for NSString" That sounds like you're forgetting to import Foundation framework.

Comment: Can we see your .h and .m? Do they inherit from NSObject? Are you declaring them before the interface and implementation? etc etc.

Comment: @matt In the original post it says not to include anything other than the text declaring the constants. That is why I did not import Foundation framework.

Comment: @Dare They don't inherit from anything - should they? I'm simply following directions from original post that says const declarations should be the only text in the file. I figured that meant not importing Foundation framework for example.

Comment: The class they're in certainly inherits from something

Comment: @Dare do you know of a full example showing exactly what they should look like? As I said, I followed instructions from referenced post word-for-word, and those instructions said nothing else in the file. I'm looking for a full and exact template of what should go in each of these files.

Comment: Voting to close this question because the OP refuses to show the actual code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the template that does seem to work. It's not different from the old answer except that you *don't* delete everything apart from the constants.

.h

```
#ifndef Project_prefs_h
#define Project_prefs_h  
#endif
extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT;
```

.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant";
```

Apart from this it appears no longer possible to use .pch file to automatically include the constants across all classes.

Comment: Are you trying to import the file where it is required?

Comment: @nischalhada yes I did import the file where it was created. That wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of Xcode there is no ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically file so you should import the file where it is required then try using the constant.

Easiest way:

```
// Prefs.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define PREFS_MY_CONSTANT @"prefs_my_constant"
```

Better way:

```
// Prefs.h
extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT;

// Prefs.m
NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant";
```

There are a few different ways to create constants in Objective-C, but the easiest way is to use #define statements.

To start, create a new header file. This is where we’ll store all the constants. Name it something original like “Constants.h”.

Here’s a sample file with a few constants:

```
//
//  Constants.h
//  App Name


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define NUM_SECTIONS        7

#define NUM_SECTION_1_ITEMS 2
#define NUM_SECTION_2_ITEMS 14
#define NUM_SECTION_3_ITEMS 5

#define APP_TITLE           @"App Name"
#define APP_AUTHOR          @"Miscellanea"
```

To use these constants in your project, you need to import your header file in each implementation file (*.m) where you’ll be referencing them.

```
#import "Constants.h"
– (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = APP_TITLE;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SECTIONS; ++ i)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I had tried this without the .pch and it still doesn't work. I have prefs.h and prefs.m exactly as you have specified (no code besides what you have in your answer). When I try to build, I get a Parse Issue in prefs.m: "Unknown type name 'NSString'

Comment: // Prefs.h
#define PREFS_MY_CONSTANT @"prefs_my_constant" use this method

Comment: thanks again, but this gives me the linker error I mentioned in my earlier  message: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_PREFS_MY_CONSTANT", referenced from:
      -[AccountInfoViewController viewDidLoad] in AccountInfoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Just create only header file. Do you know how to do that

Comment: Pop an `@import Foundation;` at the top of your `prefs.h` to fix the **Unknown type** error

Comment: @nischalhada Yes I did try creating only a header file - that gives me the linker error I just pasted in my comment and in my original file.

Comment: Create a constant with name 
Constants.h 
then dont forget to import 

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
as shown in above example

Comment: @nischalhada what worked is the following for .h #ifndef Loq_ly_prefs_h
#define Loq_ly_prefs_h


#endif


extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT; and the following for .m 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant";

Comment: @AshleyMills yes you were right about this. Perhaps it just goes without saying in the original post, but that's not how I understood their comment to delete everything apart from the constant declarations. Thank you!