# Use #define constant put in Objective C .h file bridged in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridge

I'm working on a swift project and I have made MyProjectName-Bridging-header.h
In this bridge, I have added a .h file that contains multiple constants made by

```
#define constantName VALUE
```

I need to know how to use these constants into my swift file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Do not define constants with macros

Using macros in place of global constants or functions is a sure sign of a [code smell](http://qualitycoding.org/preprocessor/) – they're not type-safe & can make debugging a nightmare. Thankfully, Swift does away with the C preprocessor, so you can no longer use them with Swift code!

You should instead be defining constants in your Objective-C headers by using global C constants.

```
static NSString* const aConstString = @"foobar";
static NSInteger const aConstInteger = 42;
```

Or if you want to keep the values out of your headers:

```
extern NSString* const aConstString;
extern NSInteger const aConstInteger;
```

```
NSString* const aConstString = @"foobar";
NSInteger const aConstInteger = 42;
```

These will then get bridged over to a Swift global constants in your auto-generated Swift header and will look like this:

```
public let aConstString: String
public let aConstInteger: Int
```

You can now access them from your Swift code.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. I'd recommend using [this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/2305521) of ObjC Constants.

I think the simplest/quickest solution is duplicating all your `.h` constant files with a `.m` and running a simple regex to convert your defines.

A simple set of regex would be: (does not treat escaped quotes)

### Find `#define`

`#define\s+(\w+)\s+(@".*")`

### Replace for .h

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const $1;`

### Replace for .m

`NSString *const $1 = $2;`

Answer (score 1):

```
make simple Constant.swift 

import UIKit

class Constant: NSObject {

    // make your constant like this get rid from macros 
    static let AppFontBold = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    static let AppFontRegular = "HelveticaNeue"
    static let iPhoneFontSize : CGFloat = 17
    static let iPadFontSize : CGFloat = 24

}

Note : you can invoke your constant like Constant.AppFontBold
```

Comment: It's not a single file, but multiple big .h files. I need to use them, not convert them to swift.

Comment: check your bridging header path or delete and make new one to try

Answer (score -1):

Generally bridging header files are used to add objective files in swift. For constants you could make constants.swift file and add your constants using var keyword.

```
var constant   =          "value"
```

Use above constant anywhere without importing constants.swift file.

Comment: It's not a single file, but multiple big .h files. I need to use them, not convert them to swift.

Comment: yes, bridging headers files are used for this purpose only. But why are you adding constants in bridging header files. just import your objective-c(.h) files in that bridging header and use them(.h) in your swift files directly i.e you don't need to import those .h files again in swift files.