# How to declare objects as constants in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, object, compile-time-constant

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) that explains very well how to declare a constant `NSString` or primitive type in Objective-C. The method worked perfectly.

I ran into a problem when, recently, I was writing an application using CoreBluetooth. There are several `CBUUID`'s that I'd like to save as constants because I will be using them frequently. In this case the `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` technique fails.

When I put this in my header file

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CBUUID *const _Nonnull kTxPowerServiceUUID;
```

and this in my .m file

```
CBUUID *const kTxPowerServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1804"];
```

I get this error

> ERROR: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

To my surprise, I get this error even when the object I am trying to initialize ***is*** a compile time constant. For example, I have several calculations in my application that involve the speed of light in meters per second. I tried creating a constant `NSNumber` to represent it. When I tried this

```
NSNumber *const kTheSpeedOfLight = @(299792458);
```

I got the same error, and resorted to declaring `kTheSpeedOfLight` as an `unsigned int`.

**So is there a way to create constants from objects in general? Or is it just for primitives and `NSString`'s?**

Comment: There is special compiler support for embedding `NSString`s in the compiled binary.  All other declarations are translated into object creation calls, so `@(int)` is translated into `[NSNumber numberWithInt:int]`.  This is not a constant.

Comment: try   declare in the header,

extern const CBUUID *const _Nonnull kTxPowerServiceUUID;
then in a .m file somewhere 

const CBUUID *const kTxPowerServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1804"];;

Comment: @DarjiJigar That won't work. That will still give the same "not a compile time constant" error.

Comment: @DarjiJigar I can confirm what rmaddy said. Just tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom try to create function for declare the vale than after access the variable

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for marking this as a duplicate. That other question was really helpful.

Comment: `NSNumber *const kTheSpeedOfLight = @(299792458);` This line is working perfect....