# In objective-c project, how can I collect all parameters(constants) in one file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wish to collect all the needed parameters/constants, structs, and enums in one separate file, so that I can easily find and edit them later. How can I achieve this goal?

I tried to put them in a separate .m file, and add this file to the current compile target. But it did not work. My .m file is as follows

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSTimeInterval const oneDay=86400;
NSTimeInterval const oneSecond=1;

typedef enum:NSUInteger {
    EventStatusPassed,
    EventStatusFinished,
} EventStatus;
```

Thank you

Comment: `oneDay=86400` this is incorrect due to DST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constants in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Constants.h file

```
@interface Constants : NSObject
    extern NSString* const URL;
@end
```

Constants.m file

```
@implementation Constants
    NSString* const someConstant = @"abcd";
@end
```

and import it in the files that you need constants

```
#import "Constants.h"
```