# Can I have a constant defined on a category in objc

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

`NSError` has a `userInfo` which is a dictionary. I would like to have a custom `NSErrorUserInfoKey`. I thought of a category for the `NSError` where I can define that key as a constant string. I know that I can't have properties in categories but is it possible and correct to add a constant to a category?

Comment: The keys are strings aren't they, so see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/299924).

Comment: Yes but is it ok to add them on a category?

Comment: Does it have a `.h` and `.m` file?  If so, then yes.

Comment: Thanks that would probably do then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have option to add properties in category using

```
objc_setAssociatedObject
```

and

```
objc_getAssociatedObject
```

`objc_setAssociatedObject` is used to set the value 
`objc_getAssociatedObject` is used to ge the value

About constants I would create another class for constant `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` and use it here. Something like CustomErrorUserInfoKeys.h