# Find NSString in const NSString *const[]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a constants.h file and declared:

```
extern NSString * check_array_editable[];
```

In the constants.m i set:

```
NSString * check_array_editable[] = { @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"9", @"11", @"14" , @"17", @"18", @"21" };
```

So is dont have to call an initializer, what i have to do if i use NSArray instead of the collection.

Now i import the constants.h and can access  check_array_editable[].
But how will i be able to get the length and the Index of a specific item like the usage of NSArray:

```
 BOOL isTheObjectThere = [check_array_editable containsObject: @"my string"];
 NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [check_array_editable indexOfObject: @"my string"];
```

---edit
I finally decidest to work with NSArray and use a inizalise void in the constants.h

```
NSArray * check_array_invisible;
NSArray * check_array_editable;
NSArray * check_array_texteingabe;
NSArray * check_array_assistent;
NSArray * check_array_functionfield;
+(void)initialize{
  check_array_invisible = @[@10, @13, @34, @35];
  check_array_editable = @[@1,@2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @9, @11, @14 , @17, @18, @21 ];
  check_array_texteingabe = @[@1, @2, @3, @9, @11, @14];
  check_array_assistent = @[@16, @35];
  check_array_functionfield = @[@32];
}
```

Comment: The NSArray initializer using Objective-C literals is as long as the C-array `NSArray * check_array_editable = @[@"1", @"2", @"3" … ];` and you have the whole convenience of the NSArray class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your declaration your array is C style array so you won't be able to use the familiar methods like `containsObject` and `indexOfObject` but you should deal with it as a C style array and search like this

```
NSString *s = @"1";
int i = 0;
while(check_array_editable[i]) {
    if( [check_array_editable[i] isEqualToString:s]) {
        NSLog(@"yeah");
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Instead you can in your implementation file declare the array like this:

```
#define check_array_editable@[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"]
```

and now you can use the fun methods like `indexOfObject`

example:

```
NSLog( @"%zd",[arrayOfStrings indexOfObject:@"2"]);
```

result:

```
2015-07-16 11:04:47.620 PROJ[881:13857] 1
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544616/static-nsarray-of-strings-how-where-to-initialize-in-a-view-controller) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436463/how-do-i-declare-an-array-as-a-constant-in-objective-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312575/how-can-i-use-an-nsarray-as-a-global-constant)

Comment: works, but i decidet to work with NSArray and a initializer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof` to determine the number of elements in your C array. Taking the `sizeof` a C array:

```
sizeof(check_array_editable)
```

returns the total size of all its elements (in your example the answer is 104 [assuming a 64-bit binary]); and in your case each element is an `NSString *` the size of which is given by:

```
sizeof(NSSString *)
```

which will return 8 [again assuming 64-bit]. Just divide the total length by the element length:

```
sizeof(check_array_editable) / sizeof(NSSString *)
```

and you get the number of elements in the array (in your example 13).

**Important**: The above will *only* work for variables declared as arrays. A variable declared with a C pointer type, which is then set to reference dynamically allocated memory, might be usable as an array but it is not one. Taking the `sizeof` such a variable returns its size - the size of a pointer - not the size of what it is currently referencing.

HTH