# NSError and __autoreleasing

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Can someone please explain to me the purpose of having `__autoreleasing` in the following sample code block?

```
- (void)execute:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {
    // do stuff, possibly assigning error if something went wrong
}
```

I removed the `__autoreleasing` and everything still seems to compile/run fine.  I started using obj-c post ARC so I never really learned/understood all those double underscore thingamajigs.  I've read the [ARC transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I don't fully understand their NSError example.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Consider how ARC works with *variables* - each reference variable has a mode (implicit or explicit): *strong*, *weak*, etc. This mode let's ARC know how to handle reads and writes to that variable; e.g. for a *strong* variable reading requires no additional action while writing requires releasing the existing reference in the variable before it is replaced by the new one. ARC needs to know the mode of any variable in order to function.

Now consider variables that themselves are passed by *reference*, e.g. for your `execute` you'll have a call along the lines of:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
...
[someObject execute:&myError]; // pass the variable itself by reference, not the variables value
```

and the body of `execute` will contain an assignment along the lines of:

```
- (void)execute:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
   ...
   if (error != NULL)
      *error = [NSError ...]; // assign indirectly via the reference to a variable
   ...
}
```

Now for that indirect assignment ARC needs to know the mode of the referenced variable so it knows how to read and write. That is what the `__autoreleasing` is in the declaration, it tells ARC that it has been passed a reference to a variable whose mode is *autoreleasing*, and that tells ARC how to read and write the contents of the variable. Remove the `__autoreleasing` and a default mode will be assumed, and in this case I'd suggest being explicit is certainly good.

The *autoreleasing* mode means the variable contains a reference which is not owned, reads should *retain* if necessary and writes can just write. It is used mainly for variables passed by reference.

You might notice that in the example above the variable `myError` has mode *strong* (implicitly) and yet it is passed by reference as *autoreleasing* - the compiler handles this automatically by introducing a temporary autoreleasing variable, copying *without* retaining the current reference in `myError` into it, and passing the temporary by reference as the argument to `execute:`. After the call returns the compiler does a normal assignment from the temporary to `myError`, which results in any old reference being released and the returned one retained.

For more details see [Apple's Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

**Followup to Comments**

Q: Is `__autoreleasing` implicitly set?

A: Well [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) document is not specific, but the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.inference) says it is implicit for indirect parameters. As above I'd recommend being explicit, clarity is a Good Thing™.

Q: Does the placement matter?

A: Yes, and no... This is a C declaration, the stuff of quiz questions ("What does the following declare..."). The qualifier should be between the two asterisks as it is a *pointer to a (variable of type) autoreleasing pointer to an object*, but Apple state the compiler is "forgiving" without being specific of what it forgives. Play it safe, put it in the right place.

Q: Should you not test for `error` being `NULL` before doing the indirect assignment?

A: Of course you should, somewhere before you do the indirection. The code shown is just an outline and such detail was elided and covered by the `...`’s. However as it has been raised a few times over the years maybe I elided too much, a suitable `if` has been added.

Comment: So is `__autoreleasing` implicitly set if I don't explicitly set it?

Also, does the placement of `__autoreleasing` matter (before, inside of, or after the asterisks)?

Comment: @chinabuffet - See followup in answer

Comment: @CRD nice answer.  But you might want to point out that you should check if `error` is `NULL` before assigning to `*error`.  Otherwise, your method could crash your app since `[foo execute:NULL]` is a perfectly valid execution and the way to say "I don't care about the error".

Comment: It looks like in XCode 6.1, if you are not explicit, you get a warning: "Method parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' with no explicit ownership"

Comment: Agreeing with @Joel, you want to check if `error` is NOT `nil` OR `NULL` before assigning `*error` or you could throw a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal.