# Swift doesn't convert Objective-C NSError** to throws

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nserror

I have some Objective-C legacy code, that declares method like

```
- (void)doSomethingWithArgument:(ArgType)argument error:(NSError **)error
```

As written here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

> Swift automatically translates Objective-C methods that produce errors
>   into methods that throw an error according to Swift’s native error
>   handling functionality.

But in my project described methods are called like this:

```
object.doSomething(argument: ArgType, error: NSErrorPointer)
```

Moreover, it throws runtime exception when I try to use them like:

```
let errorPtr = NSErrorPointer()
object.doSomething(argumentValue, error: errorPtr)
```

Do I need something more to convert Objective-C "NSError **" methods to Swift "trows" methods?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? 'throws' is available only in Swift 2.0 and higher.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Only `Objective-C` methods are translated to throwing `Swift` methods, which do return a `BOOL` (not lower-cased `bool`), or a nullable-object.
(Tested with Xcode 11.7, and Swift 5 language.)

The reason is that Cocoa methods always use a return value `NO` or `nil`
to indicate the failure of a method, and *not* just set an error object.
This is documented in
[Using and Creating Error Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html):

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method.
> Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error
> domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure
> by directly returning nil or NO, you should always check that the return
> value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object.

For example, the Objective-C interface

```
@interface OClass : NSObject

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

-(void)doSomethingWithArgument1:(int) x error:(NSError **)error;
-(BOOL)doSomethingWithArgument2:(int) x error:(NSError **)error;
-(NSString *)doSomethingWithArgument3:(int) x error:(NSError **)error;
-(NSString * _Nullable)doSomethingWithArgument4:(int) x error:(NSError **)error;
-(BOOL)doSomething:(NSError **)error;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@end
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
open class OClass : NSObject {

    open func doSomethingWithArgument1(x: Int32, error: NSErrorPointer)
    open func doSomethingWithArgument2(x: Int32) throws
    open func doSomethingWithArgument3(x: Int32, error: NSErrorPointer) -> String
    open func doSomethingWithArgument4(x: Int32) throws -> String
    open func doSomething() throws
}
```

If you can change the interface of your method then you should add a boolean
return value to indicate success or failure.

Otherwise you would call it from Swift as

```
var error : NSError?
object.doSomethingWithArgument(argumentValue, error: &error)
if let theError = error {
    print(theError)
}
```

*Remark:* At

- https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Inputs/clang-importer-sdk/usr/include/errors.h

I found that Clang has an attribute which forces a function to throw an error in Swift:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithArgument5:(int) x error:(NSError **)error
  __attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)));
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
public func doSomethingWithArgument5(x: Int32) throws
```

and seems to work "as expected". However, I could not find any official documentation
about this attribute, so it might not be a good idea to rely on it.

Comment: Thanks, really nice answer

Comment: Nice find! I found the documentation for the attributes here: https://github.com/apple/swift-clang/blob/383859a9c4b964af3d127b5cc8abd0a8f11dd164/include/clang/Basic/AttrDocs.td#L1800-L1819

Comment: Looks like this works for initializers, too: `- (instancetype _Nullable)init:(NSError**)error;`. However, to call it from Swift, I had to pass an empty tuple `()` as an argument.

Comment: Martin, is there a way to translate a closure, either as a property or a parameter?  I can't find a working example, but have been trying (to no avail): `typedef BOOL(^Snafu)(NSString*, NSError**);`, with a method of `-(void) doSomethingWithClosure: (Snafu) closure;`, and property of `@property (nonatomic, copy) Snafu _Nullable snafu;` .Thank you.

Comment: I think this answers my question (and a good test): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409191/is-it-possible-that-bridging-header-turns-void-nserror-block-objc-into

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your method return a `BOOL`, to tell the runtime that an error should or should not be thrown. Also you should add `__autoreleasing` to the error parameter, to make sure ARC doesn't accidentally release the error before you have a chance to use it:

```
- (BOOL)doSomethingWithArgument:(ArgType)argument error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

You can then call it from Swift like this:

```
do {
    object.doSomethingWithArgument(someArgument)
} catch let err as NSError {
    print("Error: \(err)")
}
```

Comment: `__autoreleasing` is actually assumed by default for an `NSError **error` parameter. Otherwise you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... another thing I learned today :) This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13590696/1974224) and the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) confirm what you said :)