# Swift try inside Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, closures, try-catch

I need to create a function `foo` that takes a throwing closure as a parameter. I can implement it with either Swift or ObjC but I need to be able to call it from both.

Like this:

```
// Swift
func bar() throws
func foo(_ block: () throws -> void)

foo {
  try bar()
}
```

and

```
// Objc
[self foo:^(
  [other barBar];
)];
```

I tried to implement it with both Swift and ObjC without succes. With Swift:

```
@objc
func foo(block: () throws -> Void)
```

I get this error:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 1 cannot be represented in Objective-C

If I try to implement it with ObjC:

```
typedef BOOL (^ThrowingBlock)(NSError **);
- (void)foo:(ThrowingBlock)block;
```

Then it does not translate to a block that throws ([as it would with a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34787941/3769338)):

```
func foo(_: (NSErrorPointer) -> Bool)
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You probably can't. As the error message tells you, a Swift `throws` function is not a possible Objective-C parameter type. You'll have to change your desires. You need the type of `block` to be a type that Objective-C can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` macro to provide a unified interface between Objective-C and Swift, with `throws` in Swift and `NSError **` in Objective-C.

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID188):

> You can use the NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT macro on an Objective-C method declaration to provide a refined Swift interface in an extension, while keeping the original implementation available to be called from the refined interface. For instance, an Objective-C method that takes one or more pointer arguments could be refined in Swift to return a tuple of values.

In your case you can declare `foo` as refined for Swift, and add a same method, in a class extension:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

- (void)foo:(void (^)(NSError **))block NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end
```

and in Swift:

```
extension MyClass {
    func foo(block: @escaping () throws -> Void) {
        // Objective-C's `foo` is now imported as `__foo`
        __foo { errPtr in
            do {
                try block()
            } catch {
                errPtr?.pointee = error as NSError
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call `foo` from both worlds, with the distinction that Objective-C code will need to pass a `NSError **` block, while Swift callers can pass a nicer `throws` closure.