# Catching Both Objective-C and Swift Exceptions with Support for Return Values

Tags: swift, objective-c, exception

I have a question on catching both Swift errors and Objective-C exceptions using a single do-catch statement.

Let's say I have a function which invokes a bunch of other functions that may either throw a Swift `Error` or an Objective-C `NSException`:

```swift
func performTasks() throws {
    functionThrowingNSException()
    try functionThrowingSwiftError()
    functionThrowingNSException()
    try functionThrowingSwiftError()
    …
}
```

The Swift function may look somewhat like this:

```swift
func functionThrowingSwiftError() throws {
    throw MyError.someError(message: "Swift error")
}

enum MyError: Error {
    case someError(message: String)
}
```

And the Objective-C part may look like this:

```swift
func functionThrowingNSException() {
    let myLibrary = MyLibrary()
    myLibrary.performRiskyTask()
}
```

```objectivec
@interface MyLibrary : NSObject

- (void)performRiskyTask;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation MyLibrary

- (void)performRiskyTask {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                   reason:@"Objective-C exception"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

@end
```

Now I would like to catch both types of exceptions in a single catch-block. If I try this, however …

```swift
do {
    try performTasks()
} catch {
    print("Error caught:", error)
}
```

…, the app crashes at runtime:

```text
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Objective-C exception'
```

As pointed out in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558361/catching-both-objective-c-and-swift-exceptions), this issue can be resolved using the following code:

```objectivec
@interface ExceptionHandling : NSObject

+ (BOOL)tryVoidObjC:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation ExceptionHandling

+ (BOOL)tryVoidObjC:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error {
    @try {
        tryBlock(error);
        return error == NULL || *error == nil;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:exception.name code:-1 userInfo:@{
                NSUnderlyingErrorKey: exception,
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: exception.reason,
                @"callStackSymbols": exception.callStackSymbols
            }];
        }
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

```swift
extension ExceptionHandling {
    static func tryVoidObjC(_ block: () throws -> Void) throws {
        try __tryVoidObjC { (errorPointer: NSErrorPointer) in
            do {
                try block()
            } catch {
                errorPointer?.pointee = error as NSError
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I can convert the NSException to a Swift error and catch it:

```swift
do {
    try performTasks()
} catch {
    print("Error caught:", error)
}
```

```swift
func performTasks() throws {
    try ExceptionHandling.tryVoidObjC {
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
    }
}
```

```text
Error caught: Error Domain=NSInternalInconsistencyException Code=-1 "Objective-C exception" UserInfo={callStackSymbols =(…), NSLocalizedDescription=Objective-C exception, NSUnderlyingError=Objective-C exception}
```

Now, the `functionThrowingNSException()` is a void function. What if I want to use an Objective-C method that can either throw an NSException *or* return a value? So something like this:

```swift
do {
    let answer = try performTasks()
    print("The answer is \(answer).")
} catch {
    print("Error caught:", error)
}
```

```swift
func performTasks() throws -> Int {
    return try ExceptionHandling.tryObjC {
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        return ultimateAnswer()
    }
}

func ultimateAnswer() -> Int {
    let myLibrary = MyLibrary()
    return myLibrary.ultimateAnswer()
}
```

```objectivec
@interface MyLibrary : NSObject

- (NSInteger)ultimateAnswer;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation MyLibrary

- (NSInteger)ultimateAnswer {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSGenericException
                                   reason:@"Computation timed out"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

@end
```

How would I go about doing that?

###### First approach:

It's important to understand how Swift translates Cocoa's error pattern:

> If the last non-block parameter of an Objective-C method is of type NSError **, Swift replaces it with the throws keyword, to indicate that the method can throw an error.
>
> […]
>
> If an error producing Objective-C method returns a BOOL value to indicate the success or failure of a method call, Swift changes the return type of the function to Void. Similarly, if an error producing Objective-C method returns a nil value to indicate the failure of a method call, Swift changes the return type of the function to a nonoptional type.
>
> Otherwise, if no convention can be inferred, the method is left intact.
>
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/about_imported_cocoa_error_parameters)

For this reason, the `+[ExceptionHandling tryVoidObjC:error:]` method (if it weren't "refined for Swift"), is translated to `func tryObjC(_ tryBlock: ((NSErrorPointer) -> Void)!) throws`.

We need to use a boolean return value for this Objective-C method, because if we were to use a void return type, no convention could be inferred and the method would instead be translated to the non-throwing function `func tryObjC(_ tryBlock: ((NSErrorPointer) -> Void)!, error: NSErrorPointer)`.

Similarly, we cannot use an integer return type because this would translate the method to `func tryObjC(_ tryBlock: ((NSErrorPointer) -> Int)!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Int`.

So one way to solve the problem would be to return an `NSNumber` instance and take care of converting it *from* and *to* an integer in the Swift refinement:

```objectivec
@interface ExceptionHandling : NSObject

+ (NSNumber *)tryObjC:(NSNumber * (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation ExceptionHandling

+ (NSNumber *)tryObjC:(NSNumber * (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error {
    @try {
        return tryBlock(error);
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:exception.name code:-1 userInfo:@{
                NSUnderlyingErrorKey: exception,
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: exception.reason,
                @"callStackSymbols": exception.callStackSymbols
            }];
        }
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

```swift
extension ExceptionHandling {
    static func tryObjC(_ block: () throws -> Int) throws -> Int {
        let number = try __tryObjC { errorPointer in
            do {
                let integer = try block()
                return NSNumber(integerLiteral: integer)
            } catch {
                errorPointer?.pointee = error as NSError
                return nil
            }
        }
        return number.intValue
    }
}
```

This solution does actually work. The code will compile and, if those other methods don't interrupt execution by throwing errors …

```swift
func functionThrowingNSException() {
    //let myLibrary = MyLibrary()
    //myLibrary.performRiskyTask()
}

func functionThrowingSwiftError() throws {
    //throw MyError.someError(message: "Swift error")
}
```

…, the exception will be caught:

```text
Error caught: Error Domain=NSGenericException Code=-1 "Computation timed out" UserInfo={callStackSymbols=(…), NSLocalizedDescription=Computation timed out, NSUnderlyingError=Computation timed out}
```

Likewise, the actual return value is printed if the library method doesn't throw:

```objectivec
@implementation MyLibrary

- (NSInteger)ultimateAnswer {
    return 42;
}

@end
```

```text
The answer is 42.
```

This solution is not ideal, however, because it would need to be re-implemented for every return type. It would be preferable for the `tryObjC` method to have a generic return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to dealing with generic return types is to replace `NSNumber *` by `id` in the Objective-C class:

```objectivec
@interface ExceptionHandling : NSObject

+ (id)tryObjC:(id (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation ExceptionHandling

+ (id)tryObjC:(id (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSError **))tryBlock error:(NSError **)error {
    @try {
        return tryBlock(error);
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:exception.name code:-1 userInfo:@{
                NSUnderlyingErrorKey: exception,
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: exception.reason,
                @"callStackSymbols": exception.callStackSymbols
            }];
        }
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Next, provide a generic Swift method as the refinement:

```swift
extension ExceptionHandling {
    static func tryObjC<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) throws -> T {
        return try __tryObjC { errorPointer in
            do {
                return try block()
            } catch {
                errorPointer?.pointee = error as NSError
                return nil
            }
        } as! T
    }
}
```

The code will compile and the result will be printed (or the NSException will be caught):

```swift
do {
    let answer = try performTasks()
    print("The answer is \(answer).")
} catch {
    print("Error caught:", error)
}
```

```swift
func performTasks() throws -> Int {
    return try ExceptionHandling.tryObjC {
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        return ultimateAnswer()
    }
}
```

```text
The answer is 42.
```

The compiler even took care of "autoboxing" the `NSInteger` to an `NSNumber *` automatically.

###### Remark:

The `+[ExceptionHandling tryObjC:error:]` method is translated to `func __tryObjC(_ tryBlock: ((NSErrorPointer) -> Any?)!) throws -> Any`.

Notice that while the `tryBlock` seems to support an optional return value, the return value of the `__tryObjC(_:)` method must be non-optional. This is in line with the excerpt from the Swift docs saying that Swift changes the return type of the Objective-C method to a non-optional type.

If we actually were to supply `nil` as the return value of the `tryBlock` …

```objectivec
@interface MyLibrary : NSObject

- (NSString *)ultimateAnswer;

@end
```

```objectivec
@implementation MyLibrary

- (NSString *)ultimateAnswer {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

```swift
func performTasks() throws -> String? {
    return try ExceptionHandling.tryObjC {
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        functionThrowingNSException()
        try functionThrowingSwiftError()
        return ultimateAnswer()
    }
}

func ultimateAnswer() -> String? {
    let myLibrary = MyLibrary()
    return myLibrary.ultimateAnswer()
}
```

…, we would get a runtime error saying …

```text
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString'
```

… because the forced cast `try __tryObjC { … } as! T` would fail.

So returning `nil` but not throwing an `NSException` is not a pattern that is supported by this solution (just like returning `nil` but not setting the error parameter is not following Cocoa's error convention).

**EDIT:** Please understand the implications of this approach pointed out in the comments below.

Comment: You're aware that this will generally leak memory if an ObjC exception is thrown, unless you add the runtime cost of `-fobjc-arc-exceptions`, right? https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions "The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer error and are not intended to be recovered from." If you want to present this answer, you should likely explain to future searcher that it generally is unsafe, and the program should generally crash itself shortly after an exception is raised, but not for Swift errors.

Comment: Also, of note is that exceptions cannot safely pass through Swift call frames — or rather, Swift does not participate in C++ exception call stack unwinding in any way, leaving you in possibly indeterminate state even after catching an exception. I don’t believe it’s considered full-blown _undefined behavior_ to catch an exception after passing through Swift, but it’s certainly not safe to continue execution afterwards. (Will find a citation for this.)

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of this. 

Unfortunately, the library I need to use ([NGA GeoPackage](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-ios) by the way) throws NSExceptions for recoverable errors rather than using Cocoa's error pattern. So I guess I have no other choice but to catch these exceptions.

Comment: I would start by working with the vendor to fix the ObjC (possibly in the form of a PR). If that wasn't possible, I would fork the project and fix the ObjC in the fork. If that wasn't possible, I would wrap this module in ObjC++ (in order to get ARC exceptions) that catches the ObjC exceptions and changes them into ObjC errors where appropriate. But I would not allow this to intermix with Swift errors.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I have now created [an issue](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-ios/issues/48) on that library's GitHub page. I guess forking the repo and fixing the code myself is not option. (A quick search for "[NSException raise" is giving me 109 code results already.) For now, I guess I'll either use an Objective-C++ wrapper or the `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` option (at added runtime cost).

Comment: Very well written up issue, by the way. You did a lot of good research to explain it for them.