# In Swift, an Objective-C BOOL inferred as `()` instead of Bool

Tags: swift, objective-c

I've got a method written in Objective-C which returns a `BOOL`, for example:

```objectivec
 (BOOL)methodName:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)params callback:(void(^)(NSString *_Nullable, ErrorInformation *_Nullable))callback error:(NSError *_Nullable *_Nullable)errorPtr;
```

### Usage in Swift

I get the error, `Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected condition type 'Bool'`. I thinks that `ret` is of type `()`, instead of `BOOL`. Looking at the implementation, this value is mutated inside `dispatch_sync`.

```swift
let ret = try! methodName()
// I've tried a bunch of different syntaxes below:
if (ret) { <--- Xcode warning: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected condition type 'Bool'

}
```

---

It is not nice to see this method has 3 ways of indicating failure, but I didn't design it  and frankly my objective-C is not good:

- `errorPtr`, which is automatically turned into `do/try/catch` in Swift
- `ErrorInformation` passed in the callback
- `BOOL` return value, which I am struggling with.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34786115/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned `BOOL` is part of the `NSError` processing that is converted in Swift into a `throws` function (if the method returns a value, Swift will convert it from `nullable` to `nonnull`).

`YES` is returned if the method succeeds (there is no error), `NO` is returned  when the method fails.

In Swift:

```
do {
   try methodName()
   // method succeeded
} catch {
  // method failed
}
```

The `ErrorInformation` in the callback is probably related to asynchronous errors, probably similar to a `Result<String, Error>` in Swift.

References:

1. [Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods (Obj-C)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html)
2. [Improved NSError Bridging (Swift Evolution 0112)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md)

Comment: Thanks!  Could you point me to the docs for the `NSError` processing? I wanted to understand why in Objective-C the API would both have `ret` (BOOL return value) and a `nsError` pointer.

Comment: @BenButterworth Added references :) In short, you would use the returned value for a fast check success/fail and you would use the error parameter if you wanted to know the exact error. You could pass `NULL` to the error parameter.

Comment: "why in Objective-C the API would both have ret (BOOL return value) and a nsError pointer" Because the pointer might be non nil on success. So in Objective C first you look at the Bool, and if NO you look at the error. That's tricky. Whole point is that Swift wraps it for you.