# What does "*__strong*" mean?

Tags: objective-c

There is a method:

```
- (void)doSmth:(NSString *__strong*)str {
    NSLog(@"%@", *str);
}
```

What does it mean when *__strong* follows the class of a method parameter? Why are there two asterisks?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587742/nserror-and-autoreleasing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two asterisks mean it's a pointer to a pointer.

`__strong` is the opposite of `__weak` which you probably already know. It means we are talking about a strong reference here. While we hold to that reference, the object won't be deallocated.

Also we need to know that writing `__strong Type *varName` is technically wrong (although it works and almost everybody uses it). The correct syntax is `Type * __strong varName`.

Your syntax is a pointer to a strong reference to `NSString`. It means that when an object is returned from the method, there must be a `release` call from ARC to properly deallocate that object.

Please see the related question:
[NSError and __autoreleasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587742/nserror-and-autoreleasing) and the official documentation:
[Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Though this question has already answer, but people need to know the exact words or easiest description.

**__strong**

> An object remains “alive” as long as there is a strong pointer to it.
>
> When an object is assigned to that pointer, it is retained for as long as that pointer refers to it
>
> When you want to ensure the object you are referencing is not deallocated while you are still using it.

Above points are meaning of  __strong.

[The Best Example of __strong from BJ Homer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262535/explanation-of-strong-and-weak-storage-in-ios5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Here dog is a object, and that the dog wants to run away (be deallocated).
>
> Strong pointers are like a leash on the dog. As long as you have the
>   leash attached to the dog, the dog will not run away. If five people
>   attach their leash to one dog, (five strong pointers to one object),
>   then the dog will not run away until all five leashes are detached.
>
> Weak pointers, on the other hand, are like little kids pointing at the
>   dog and saying "Look! A dog!" As long as the dog is still on the
>   leash, the little kids can still see the dog, and they'll still point
>   to it. As soon as all the leashes are detached, though, the dog runs
>   away no matter how many little kids are pointing to it.
>
> As soon as the last strong pointer (leash) no longer points to an
>   object, the object will be deallocated, and all weak pointers will be
>   zeroed out.

**Two asterisks**

> It is pointer to pointer

If you use pointer to pointer you have to do like Sulthan said  **when an object is returned from the method, there must be a release call from ARC to properly deallocate that object.**
So we have to know the way of pointer to pointer use

[Here is the way for Handling pointer to pointer ownership issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc)