# Why the pointer value is changed when passing by reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Why the following NSLog results are different?

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
NSLog(@"%p",&view); //0x7fff59c86848
[self test:&view];

-(void)test:(UIView **)view{
   NSLog(@"%p",view); // 0x7fff59c86840
}
```

While the following NSLog results are same?

```
 NSInteger j = 1;
 NSLog(@"%p", &j);//0x7fff5edc7ff8
 [self test1:&j];

- (void)test1:(NSInteger *)j{
   NSLog(@"%p", j);//0x7fff5edc7ff8
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question with a non-obvious answer.

It is all to do with the *ownership qualifiers* associated with variables. When you declare:

```
NSView *view;
```

this is a shorthand for:

```
NSView __strong * view;
```

i.e. the reference is held strongly by the variable `view`.

However when you declare:

```
-(void)test:(UIView **)view
```

this is shorthand for:

```
-(void)test:(UIView * __autoreleasing *)view
```

here `view` is of type pointer to variable of type __autoreleasing pointer to `UIView`.

The reason for this difference, `__strong` vs. `__autoreleasing`, is due to what Apple term's call-by-writeback and is explained in [*Variable Qualifiers* in Apple's "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) and in [*Ownership qualification* in *CLANG Documentation: Automatic Reference Counting*](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). It is also explained the SO questions [Handling Pointer-to-Pointer Ownership Issues in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc) and [NSError and __autoreleasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587742/nserror-and-autoreleasing).

In brief: a pointer to `__strong` variable cannot be passed as a pointer to an `__autoreleasing` one. To support you doing this the compiler introduces a hidden temporary variable and passes its address instead. I.e. your code is effectively compiled as:

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
NSLog(@"%p",&view);
UIView __autoreleasing * compilerTemp = view;
[self test:&compilerTemp];
view = compilerTemp;
```

Hence why you see a different address.

Comment: Thanks,  your answer is really accurate. The reverse engineering result worked as you say. And the addresses are same in MRC.