# Initializing Global Variables in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to initialize global variables, however I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I get an error.

Right now, I have a Globals.h file that I import into my AppDelegate. Here, I declare:

```
#ifndef Globals_h
#define Globals_h

#endif /* Globals_h */

extern NSArray *CompetencyOne;
extern NSArray *CompetencyTwo;
extern NSArray *CompetencyThree;
extern NSArray *CompetencyFour;
extern NSArray *CompetencyFive;
extern NSArray *CompetencySix;
extern NSArray *CompetencySeven;
extern NSArray *CompetencyEight;
extern NSArray *CompetencyNine;
extern NSArray *CompetencyTen;
extern NSArray *CompetencyEleven;
extern NSArray *CompetencyTwelve;
extern NSArray *Competencies;
```

Then, I'm not sure where to define these arrays. I tried in AppDelegate.m in the didFinishWithLaunchingOptions method, and the ViewController's viewDidLoad method, and I created a separate method,

```
-(void) initializeCompetencies{ <arrays with values>}
```

in the ViewController, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Competencies", referenced from:
  -[QuestionViewController viewDidLoad] in QuestionViewController.o
  -[QuestionViewController changed:] in QuestionViewController.o
  -[QuestionViewController nextMilestone:] in QuestionViewController.o
  -[QuestionViewController pressBack:] in QuestionViewController.o
  -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyEight", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyEleven", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyFive", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyFour", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyNine", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyOne", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencySeven", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencySix", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyTen", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyThree", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyTwelve", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
  "_CompetencyTwo", referenced from:
      -[QuestionViewController initializeCompetencies] in QuestionViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas how to properly declare and initialize global arrays? Or, how to fix this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C objects are, with the exception of NSString constants, only ever created at runtime, thus you can't use an expression to initialize them otherwise you'll get *error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant*

If you declare:

```
//Globals.h
extern NSArray *CompetencyOne;

//Globals.m
NSArray *CompetencyOne = nil; //this works coz nil is compile time constant
```

Please check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436463/how-do-i-declare-an-array-as-a-constant-in-objective-c)

Comment: The `= nil` is actually not necessary because all "objects of static storage duration" are initialized to zero. That's from the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring and initializing is not enough. You also have to **define** the variables.

Add a Globals.m file and copy the declarations, removing `extern`:

```
// Globals.m:

NSArray *CompetencyOne;
NSArray *CompetencyTwo;
NSArray *CompetencyThree;
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I have a Globals.m file with a method -(void) initializeCompetencies { <array definitions> }. Now, how do I get that info to my viewController?

Comment: Your Globals.m should simply have the arrays declared at the top of the class, i.e

 NSArray *CompetencyOne = @{....};

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, arrays are tricky because they're not compile time constants.  You'll have to do this:

`Constants.h`

```
extern NSArray *myArray;
```

`Constants.m`

```
NSArray *myArray = nil;
```

Then, somewhere on app initialize, probably app delegate did finish launching call your function:

```
myArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Logan. To clarify, where in the .h and .m do I declare and initialize the arrays?

Comment: Declare the arrays anywhere directly in the file, then initialize maybe in a global function called from app delegate did finish launching

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like you want an object to create immutable arrays for consumption within the app.

How about a class called `CompentencyFactory` that has a bunch of static methods:

```
+ (NSArray *) competencyOne;
+ (NSArray *) competencyTwo;
```

etc that look like this:

```
+ (NSArray *) competencyOne {
    return @[
        @"foo",
        @"bar",
        @"fubnut"
    ];
}
```

That you can reference throughout the app like:

```
NSArray *comp = [CompetencyFactory competencyOne];
```