# Uiimage wrong initialization and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class where I have:

```
static UiImage *image;
```

In the same class I have a method `setImage (UiImage*) imag`

```
{self.image= [[Uiimage alloc]init]; //*
self.image=imag;}
```

In another class I have

```
[myFirstClass setImage: (uiimage)]
```

This uiimage exists .

The app frezees and it stops at (*). Houndreds of proces start at this line. I also see EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following instead...

```
- (void)setImage (UiImage*)anImage {
  [image release];
  image = [anImage retain];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a property `image` then you're getting into infinite loop by calling your setter from setter.

Comment: i don t have property in h file i just declared it static  in m file . I am moving now from java to objective c...and principles are different and i do a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You have declared image

```
static UiImage *image;
```

Is that because you wish to initialise it once and thereafter refer to it - as a constant? If so, a good way to do this is to override the getter accessor method for image.

```
// foo.h
class foo {
    UIImage* image_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* image;

// foo.m
@synthesize image = image_;

-(UIImage*)image {
    if (image_ == nil) {
        //set the image here
        image_ = [[UIImage alloc] init];    
    }
    return image_
}
```

Then in client code, the first time you refer to foo.image it will be instantiated. The second and every other time you refer to it, it will already have a value.

```
// elsewhere in foo.m

UIImageView* fooImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];

// bar.m

UIImageView* barImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:foo.image];
```

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059708/defining-a-constant-in-objective-c) answer also for reference.